# Integer to base-x system using recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive code that can convert a number to any base system. for example, the integer 10 into binary would convert to 1010

So far I have this but I'm having "None" in between my output. Can anyone help me with my code?

```
def convert(a,b):
    add = a%b
    if a<=1:
        return a
    else:
        print(base(a//b,b), add)
```

my idea is that a%b is the number to add to the end of the number and a//b is the recursive part where it uses the answer of the previous binary number so 10 in base 2 is just convert(5,2) and add the 0 at the end since a//b=5 and a%b=0 which = 1010

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063425/python-elegant-inverse-function-of-intstring-base.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an integer to the shortest url-safe string in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561486/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-the-shortest-url-safe-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You have no return statement in your else block, and you have no recursive call to `convert`.

I think you want:

```
if a<=1:
    return str(a)
else:
    return str(convert(a//b,b)) + str(add)
```

as in

```
>>> def convert(a,b):
...   add = a%b
...   if a<=1:
...     return str(a)
...   else:
...     return str(convert(a//b,b)) + str(add)
... 
>>> convert(10,2)
'1010'
```

In general, try to avoid mixing types in recursive functions.  It is most often the case that both your base case and your recursive case should return the same type.

Comment: You probably ought to index into a table of digits instead of using `str()` if you want to support bases greater than 10.

Comment: You've a leading '0' issue -- i.e. `convert(10, 5)` returns '020' instead of '20'

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you structure your code in a more precise way. You can split the vaguely-specified task you mention along different sub-tasks, e.g.:

- determine and normalize the signs of
  the number and base (do you *need* to
  support negative bases, or can you
  just raise an exception?), also
  ensuring an immediate exception gets
  raised in error cases (e.g. a base of
  `0` or `1`);
- write a function that (give positive and
  correct values for `a` and `b`) returns a
  "sequence of digits" to represent `a` in
  base `b`, where a "digit" is an integer
  between `0` included and `b` excluded;
- write a function that given a's sign and
  sequence-of-digits expansions builds and
  returns a string representation -- depends
  on how you want to represent very large
  "digits" when b is large, say > 36 if you
  want to use digits, then ASCII letters,
  for the first 36 digits in the obvious
  way; maybe you should accept an "alphabet"
  string to use for the purpose (and the
  first function above should raise an exception
  when b's too large for the given alphabet)
- write a function that uses all the above ones
  to print the string out

Of these tasks, only the second one can be seen as suitable to a "recursive" implementation if one insists (though an iterative implementation is in fact much more natural!) -- given that this is homework, I guess you'll have to do it recursively because that's part of the assigned task, ah well!-).  But, for reference, one obvious way to iterate would be:

```
  def digitsequence(a, b):
    results = []
    while True:
      results.append(a % b)
      if a < b: break
      a //= b
    return reversed(results)
```

assuming one wants the digit sequence in the "big endian" order we're used to from the way positional decimal notation entered Western culture (it was the more naturally-computed little-endian order in the Arabic original... but Arab being written right-to-left, the literal transcription of that order in European languages, written left-to-right, became big-endian!-).

Anyway, you can take simple, linear recursion as a way to "reverse" things implicitly (you could say such recursion "hides" a last-in, first-out stack, which is clearly a way to reverse a sequence;-), which I guess is where the recursion spec in the homework assignment may be coming from;-).

Answer (score 0):

The `convert` function returns None, and `print` prints it. You should either remove the `print` call, or accumulate the result as a string and return it.

(I'm assuming that the call to `base` is actually meant to be a recursive call to `convert`.)

Comment: yes base is actually suppose to be convert. 

one of the examples given is this:
convert(10,2)
1 0 1 0
when i remove the print and put return, it gives me this "(((1, 0), 1), 0)"

Comment: That's because the comma operator constructs a tuple.  See my response which uses string concatenation instead.

Comment: i dont think my outcome is suppose to be a string, it should look like this example given: 1 0 1 0

Comment: What do you want it to be, then?  It has to be something.  If you want spaces in the middle then add spaces.

Comment: sorry i'm new to python. how would you add spaces?

Comment: like `str(convert(a//b,b)) + " " + str(add)`, or more Pythonically, `' '.join([str(convert(a//b,b)), str(add)])`

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on making a pip package for this.

I recommend you use my bases.py https://github.com/kamijoutouma/bases.py which was inspired by bases.js

```
from bases import Bases
bases = Bases()

bases.toBase16(200)                // => 'c8'
bases.toBase(200, 16)              // => 'c8'
bases.toBase62(99999)              // => 'q0T'
bases.toBase(200, 62)              // => 'q0T'
bases.toAlphabet(300, 'aAbBcC')    // => 'Abba'

bases.fromBase16('c8')               // => 200
bases.fromBase('c8', 16)             // => 200
bases.fromBase62('q0T')              // => 99999
bases.fromBase('q0T', 62)            // => 99999
bases.fromAlphabet('Abba', 'aAbBcC') // => 300
```

refer to https://github.com/kamijoutouma/bases.py#known-basesalphabets
for what bases are usable

For your particular question

If your looking to go binary and back you can do

```
>>> from bases import Bases
>>> bases = Bases()
>>> bases.toBase(200,2)
'11001000'
>>> bases.fromBase('11001000',2)
200
>>> bases.toBase2(200)
'11001000'
>>> bases.fromBase2('11001000')
200
```

Have Fun !!!

And again for a list of usable bases with this library refer to https://github.com/kamijoutouma/bases.py#known-basesalphabets

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursive solution (with limitations) and code to test it:

```
from string import hexdigits

def convert(a, b):

    return '0' if a == 0 else convert(a // b, b).lstrip('0') + hexdigits[a % b]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Test code

    from random import randint

    for _ in range(10):
        number = randint(0, 1000)
        base = randint(2, 16)

        conversion = convert(number, base)

        print(number, "base", base, "->", conversion, "->", int(conversion, base), "base", base)
```

Limitations include lack of support for negative numbers; currently limited to bases in the range 2 - 16; doesn't test for invalid arguments.

**TEST RUN**

```
% python3 test.py
127 base 3 -> 11201 -> 127 base 3
666 base 3 -> 220200 -> 666 base 3
348 base 2 -> 101011100 -> 348 base 2
139 base 10 -> 139 -> 139 base 10
464 base 7 -> 1232 -> 464 base 7
330 base 11 -> 280 -> 330 base 11
633 base 10 -> 633 -> 633 base 10
789 base 4 -> 30111 -> 789 base 4
355 base 15 -> 18a -> 355 base 15
582 base 8 -> 1106 -> 582 base 8
%
```