# How to convert an integer to a string in any base?

Tags: python, radix

Python allows easy creation of an integer from a string of a given base via

```
int(str, base).
```

I want to perform the inverse: **creation of a string from an integer**, 
i.e. I want some function `int2base(num, base)`, such that:

```
int(int2base(x, b), b) == x
```

The function name/argument order is unimportant.

For any number `x` and base `b` that `int()` will accept.

This is an easy function to write: in fact it's easier than describing it in this question. However, I feel like I must be missing something.

I know about the functions `bin`, `oct`, `hex`, but I cannot use them for a few reasons:

- Those functions are not available on older versions of Python, with which I need compatibility with (2.2)
- I want a general solution that can be called the same way for different bases
- I want to allow bases other than 2, 8, 16

#### Related

- [Python elegant inverse function of int(string, base)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063425/python-elegant-inverse-function-of-intstring-base)
- [Integer to base-x system using recursion in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088201/integer-to-base-x-system-using-recursion-in-python)
- [Base 62 conversion in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119722/base-62-conversion-in-python)
- [How to convert an integer to the shortest url-safe string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561486/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-the-shortest-url-safe-string-in-python)

Comment: Surprisingly no one gave a solution which works with arbitrary big base (1023). If you need it, check my solution which works for every base (2 to inf) http://stackoverflow.com/a/28666223/1090562

Comment: I have incorporated the solution with arbitrary big bases into my code as standard for bases larger 62 and provided also reverse conversion in the same function. So if there is anyone interested, just check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71027453/7711283 .

Comment: Hi, there exists a library called Basencode for this problem, please check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74324587/13981530). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 127, accepted):

If you need compatibility with ancient versions of Python, you can either use [gmpy](https://github.com/aleaxit/gmpy) (which does include a fast, completely general int-to-string conversion function, and can be built for such ancient versions – you may need to try older releases since the recent ones have not been tested for venerable Python and GMP releases, only somewhat recent ones), or, for less speed but more convenience, use Python code – e.g., for Python 2, most simply:

```py
import string
digs = string.digits + string.ascii_letters


def int2base(x, base):
    if x < 0:
        sign = -1
    elif x == 0:
        return digs[0]
    else:
        sign = 1

    x *= sign
    digits = []

    while x:
        digits.append(digs[int(x % base)])
        x = int(x / base)

    if sign < 0:
        digits.append('-')

    digits.reverse()

    return ''.join(digits)
```

For Python 3, `int(x / base)` leads to incorrect results, and must be changed to `x // base`:

```py
import string
digs = string.digits + string.ascii_letters


def int2base(x, base):
    if x < 0:
        sign = -1
    elif x == 0:
        return digs[0]
    else:
        sign = 1

    x *= sign
    digits = []

    while x:
        digits.append(digs[x % base])
        x = x // base

    if sign < 0:
        digits.append('-')

    digits.reverse()

    return ''.join(digits)
```

Comment: Just in (gmpy2) case the func Alex speaks of seems to be `gmpy2.digits(x, base)`.

Comment: It was brought to my attention that some cases need a base > 36 and so digs should be `digs = string.digits + string.lowercase + string.uppercase`

Comment: (or `string.digits + string.letters`)

Comment: Any idea why the convert-base-N-to-string isn't included by default in Python? (It is in Javascript.) Yeah, we can all write our own implementation, but I've been searching around on this site and elsewhere, and many of them have bugs. Better to have one tested, reputable version included in the core distribution.

Comment: Found a small bug in this excellent routine for the zero case when using a number system that does not start with '0'.  Only a one line change, instead of elif x==0: return '0'   =====> needs to be elif x==0: return digs[0]

Comment: Might be good to add a check that 2 <= base <= 62. Otherwise, if e.g. 1 is passed in for base, it will go into an infinite loop.

Comment: Should the reverse be there? 
>>> int2base(26, 26)
'BA'
With reverse taken out:
>>> int2base(26, 26)
'AB'

Comment: In Python 2, use `string.ascii_letters` instead of `string.letters`. Works in at least Python 2.7 too; haven't tested 2.6.

Comment: `string.letters` won't work on Python 3, you need to use `string.ascii_letters`. See here in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561432/what-is-the-equivalence-in-python-3-of-letters-in-python-2)

Comment: I have found that in Python 3 (tested with 3.4.3 on Windows) the `x /= base` will cause problems because the integer will become a decimal number. I fixed it with `x = int(x / base)`

Comment: Add `if base == 1: return ''.join(['1' for _ in range(x)])` to the start of the function for [unary (base-1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system) support ;)

Comment: @lordscales91 You can also use `x //= base` which behaves like `/=` in Python 2 in dropping the decimal. This answer should include a disclaimer that it's for Python 2.

Comment: Sooner or later someone will get an obscenity as a result of this, as I just realised (in testing, fortunately, as my users would *not* smile and move on). Solution - have a different set of digs that excludes vowels

Comment: `int(x / base)` still leads to incorrect results. The correct fix is `x // base`.

Comment: @WGH what special cases would cause that issue?

Comment: @vikarjramun A great example is `9223372036854776832`, or `((1<<53)+1) << 10`. Using `x // base` gives the correct result, `1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000`, while using the code in the sample will give `1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh ah, so the issue is imprecision of floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 233):

Surprisingly, people were giving only solutions that convert to small bases (smaller than the length of the English alphabet). There was no attempt to give a solution which converts to any arbitrary base from 2 to infinity.

So here is a super simple solution:

```
def numberToBase(n, b):
    if n == 0:
        return [0]
    digits = []
    while n:
        digits.append(int(n % b))
        n //= b
    return digits[::-1]
```

so if you need to convert some super huge number to the base `577`,

`numberToBase(67854 ** 15 - 102, 577)`, will give you a correct solution:
`[4, 473, 131, 96, 431, 285, 524, 486, 28, 23, 16, 82, 292, 538, 149, 25, 41, 483, 100, 517, 131, 28, 0, 435, 197, 264, 455]`,

Which you can later convert to any base you want

1. at some point of time you will notice that sometimes there is no built-in library function to do things that you want, so you need to write your own. If you disagree, post you own solution with a built-in function which can convert a base 10 number to base 577.
2. this is due to lack of understanding what a number in some base means.
3. I encourage you to think for a little bit why base in your method works only for n <= 36. Once you are done, it will be obvious why my function returns a list and has the signature it has.

Comment: Excellent answer! Good thinking leaving the number in a list; it makes it easier to come up with one's own character representation of numbers in different bases.

Comment: How would you then convert that list into a single character representation, if you had for example a string of characters like 0-9 plus A-Z plus 541 extra unicode characters?
`s = "0123456789ABCDEF"`
`n = [15,1,13]`
`"".join([s[x] for x in n])`

Comment: @PhilHibbs Sure, that way works. Of course, you have to decide which symbols to use and in what order.

Comment: You can extend your answer to include base 1.

`if b == 1: return n * [1]`

Comment: Hi, a reply to point 1 - we do have a library for this, please check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74324587/13981530). +1 for your valuable answer - my answer just adds to yours!

Comment: How would you convert that list back into a single number? Knowing it's the same base?

ex: 577 in this case

Comment: This is an interesting answer. On the one hand, it gets nicely at the abstract concept that an arbitrary base is just a positional numbering system, so returning an array of numbers for each place is sort of reasonable. On the other hand, when speaking of a "base", I think most people (and wikipedia's entry on Radix would imply) that one is speaking _specifically_ about the _digits_ used to _represent_ a number in such system. Converting to digits is fundamentally a part of the problem -- we want a string of characters, not an array of numbers. For bases up to 36, there are standard choices.

Comment: This is wrong. Doesn't achieve the requested `int(int2base(x, b), b) == x`. Not even if you used the requested name.

Comment: Why `int(n % b)` instead of just `n % b`?

Answer (score 124):

```
"{0:b}".format(100) # bin: 1100100
"{0:x}".format(100) # hex: 64
"{0:o}".format(100) # oct: 144
```

Comment: But it only does those three bases?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you can't specify custom int base. More info is here: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: The `0` is unnecessary. Here's the Python 2 documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Comment: You can achieve the same results with `hex(100)[2:]`, `oct(100)[2:]` and `bin(100)[2:]`.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev: It's only unnecessary on 2.7/3.1+. On 2.6, the explicit position (or name) is required.

Comment: Just a minor correction to @ Sassan's comment above - for oct, it should be `oct(100)[1:]` not `oct(100)[2:]`. (oct numbers are represented by a single leading 0).

Comment: I think you're mistaken @Hari: [The Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#oct) say `oct` does the following: `Convert an integer number to an octal string prefixed with “0o”.`, and I also was able to confirm that on my own interpreter.

Answer (score 104):

```py
def baseN(num,b,numerals="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
    return ((num == 0) and numerals[0]) or (baseN(num // b, b, numerals).lstrip(numerals[0]) + numerals[num % b])
```

ref:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65212/

Please be aware that this may lead to

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

for very big integers.

Comment: Elegant in its brevity.  It seems to work under python 2.2.3 for non-negative integers.  A negative number infinitely recurses.

Comment: +1 useful; fixed a problem when numerals didn't start with '0'

Comment: This fails silently (a) when base is > `len(numerals)`, and (b) `num % b` is, by luck, < `len(numerals)`.  e.g. although the `numerals` string is only 36 characters in length, baseN(60, 40) returns `'1k'` while baseN(79, 40) raises an `IndexError`.  Both should raise some kind of error.  The code should be revised to raise an error if `not 2 <= base <= len(numerals)`.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson, only if your base is not fixed in advance.

Comment: @osa, my point is the code as-written fails in a very bad way (silently, giving misleading answer) and could be fixed easily. If you are saying there would be no error if you knew in advance, for certain, that `b` would not exceed `len(numerals)`, well, good luck to you.

Comment: I guess it's questionable whether the "1k" result is really wrong or not. If we give a long enough string of numerals, the result is still the same. The IndexError should clearly be handled though.

Comment: +1 for being the smallest bit of code here. The other comments are true, it doesn't properly handle some edge cases, but this is a good substitute when you have a known, limited set of bases and inputs, and limited access to third-party libraries.

Comment: My friend and I were debating a "better approximate Pi day in a different base", so I modified your code to handle floats: https://gist.github.com/tigerhawkvok/5c619465f9ccab0eb25ee470708bbf16 (the answer is "Base 11 Pi Day" on March 16 at 3:07:02 PM, `3.16150702865a484`)

Comment: The use of short-circuiting here seems needlessly confusing...why not just use an if statement...the line `return numerals[0] if num == 0 else baseN(num // b, b, numerals).lstrip(numerals[0]) + numerals[num % b]` is just as brief.

Comment: Alternatively, `def num2str(num, chars): return chars[num] if num < len(chars) else num2str(num // len(chars)) + chars[num % len(chars)]`. Then you can create functions for radixes you need. Or one function (a wrapper) for an arbitrary radix. And as you can see `lstrip()` can be avoided.

Comment: Inverse to this (string to integer) in case anyone needs it: ```def n_base(num, b, numerals="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"): return 0 if len(num) == 0 else numerals.find(num[-1]) + n_base(num[:-1], b, numerals) * b```

Answer (score 85):

```
>>> numpy.base_repr(10, base=3)
'101'
```

Note that `numpy.base_repr()` has a limit of 36 as its base. Otherwise it throws a `ValueError`

Comment: Nice solution.  In my case, I was avoiding numpy in `clac` for loading-time concerns.  Preloading numpy more than triples the runtime of simple expression evaluation in clac: e.g.  `clac 1+1`   went from about 40ms to 140ms.

Comment: Which matches the limitation of the built in "int" function.  Larger bases require deciding on what to do when the letters run out,

Comment: I guess this is what most people who reach this question are looking for.

Answer (score 35):

### Recursive

I would **simplify** the [most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2267428/6196010) to:

```
base_string = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
def to_base(number, base): 
    return "0" if not number else to_base(number // base, base).lstrip("0") + base_string[number % base_string]
```

With the same advice for `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp` on very large integers and negative numbers. (You could use[`sys.setrecursionlimit(new_limit)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit))

### Iterative

To **avoid recursion problems**:

```
base_string = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
def to_base(number, base):
    result = ""
    while number:
        result += base_string[number % base]
        number //= base
    return result[::-1] or "0"
```

Comment: Beautifully refactored, and without library.

Comment: Shouldn't the stop condition be `return BS[0] if not n` then ? Just in case you want to use fancy digits, like I do :)

Comment: @ArnaudP agreed. This one works for me: `return BS[n] if n < b else to_base(n // b) + BN[n % b]`

Comment: can also use `divmod` in the iterative approach since one needs both the divisor and remainder, like so `number, remainder = divmod(number, base)`

Comment: I believe `base_string[number % base_string]` should be `base_string[number % base]`

Answer (score 22):

Great answers!
I guess the answer to my question was "no" I was not missing some obvious solution. 
Here is the function I will use that condenses the good ideas expressed in the answers.

- allow caller-supplied mapping of characters (allows base64 encode)
- checks for negative and zero
- maps complex numbers into tuples of strings

```
def int2base(x,b,alphabet='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'):
    'convert an integer to its string representation in a given base'
    if b<2 or b>len(alphabet):
        if b==64: # assume base64 rather than raise error
            alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
        else:
            raise AssertionError("int2base base out of range")
    if isinstance(x,complex): # return a tuple
        return ( int2base(x.real,b,alphabet) , int2base(x.imag,b,alphabet) )
    if x<=0:
        if x==0:
            return alphabet[0]
        else:
            return  '-' + int2base(-x,b,alphabet)
    # else x is non-negative real
    rets=''
    while x>0:
        x,idx = divmod(x,b)
        rets = alphabet[idx] + rets
    return rets
```

Comment: How do you convert the base64 output of our function back to an integer?

Answer (score 15):

You could use `baseconv.py` from my project: https://github.com/semente/python-baseconv

Sample usage:

```
>>> from baseconv import BaseConverter
>>> base20 = BaseConverter('0123456789abcdefghij')
>>> base20.encode(1234)
'31e'
>>> base20.decode('31e')
'1234'
>>> base20.encode(-1234)
'-31e'
>>> base20.decode('-31e')
'-1234'
>>> base11 = BaseConverter('0123456789-', sign='$')
>>> base11.encode('$1234')
'$-22'
>>> base11.decode('$-22')
'$1234'
```

There is some bultin converters as for example `baseconv.base2`, `baseconv.base16` and `baseconv.base64`.

Answer (score 5):

```
def base(decimal ,base) :
    list = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    other_base = ""
    while decimal != 0 :
        other_base = list[decimal % base] + other_base
        decimal    = decimal / base
    if other_base == "":
        other_base = "0"
    return other_base

print base(31 ,16)
```

output:

> "1F"

Comment: `other-base` is the same as `other - base`, so you should use `other_base`

Comment: Also, this doesn't work correctly if `decimal` is zero.

Answer (score 5):

```py
def base_conversion(num, base):
    digits = []
    while num > 0:
        num, remainder = divmod(num, base)
        digits.append(remainder)
    return digits[::-1]
```

Comment: By replacing the last line with `return ''.join(map(str, digits[::-1]))`, it's even more useful in bases between 2 and 10. It's not working for base 1.

Comment: It also doesn't work with `num=0`.

Answer (score 4):

I made a pip package for this.

I recommend you use my bases.py https://github.com/kamijoutouma/bases.py which was inspired by bases.js

```
from bases import Bases
bases = Bases()

bases.toBase16(200)                // => 'c8'
bases.toBase(200, 16)              // => 'c8'
bases.toBase62(99999)              // => 'q0T'
bases.toBase(200, 62)              // => 'q0T'
bases.toAlphabet(300, 'aAbBcC')    // => 'Abba'

bases.fromBase16('c8')               // => 200
bases.fromBase('c8', 16)             // => 200
bases.fromBase62('q0T')              // => 99999
bases.fromBase('q0T', 62)            // => 99999
bases.fromAlphabet('Abba', 'aAbBcC') // => 300
```

refer to https://github.com/kamijoutouma/bases.py#known-basesalphabets
for what bases are usable

EDIT:
pip link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bases.py/0.2.2

Comment: This works like a charm for the [known bases specified](https://github.com/kamijoutouma/bases.py#known-basesalphabets).

Comment: This is by far the best answer! And thanks for the pip packaging!

Answer (score 3):

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65212/

```
def base10toN(num,n):
    """Change a  to a base-n number.
    Up to base-36 is supported without special notation."""
    num_rep={10:'a',
         11:'b',
         12:'c',
         13:'d',
         14:'e',
         15:'f',
         16:'g',
         17:'h',
         18:'i',
         19:'j',
         20:'k',
         21:'l',
         22:'m',
         23:'n',
         24:'o',
         25:'p',
         26:'q',
         27:'r',
         28:'s',
         29:'t',
         30:'u',
         31:'v',
         32:'w',
         33:'x',
         34:'y',
         35:'z'}
    new_num_string=''
    current=num
    while current!=0:
        remainder=current%n
        if 36>remainder>9:
            remainder_string=num_rep[remainder]
        elif remainder>=36:
            remainder_string='('+str(remainder)+')'
        else:
            remainder_string=str(remainder)
        new_num_string=remainder_string+new_num_string
        current=current/n
    return new_num_string
```

Here's another one from the same link

```
def baseconvert(n, base):
    """convert positive decimal integer n to equivalent in another base (2-36)"""

    digits = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    try:
        n = int(n)
        base = int(base)
    except:
        return ""

    if n < 0 or base < 2 or base > 36:
        return ""

    s = ""
    while 1:
        r = n % base
        s = digits[r] + s
        n = n / base
        if n == 0:
            break

    return s
```

Comment: base10toN does not account for the case of num == 0.

Answer (score 2):

While the currently [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28666223/13981530) is definitely an awesome solution, there remains more customization users might like.

[Basencode](https://pypi.org/project/basencode/) adds some of these features, including conversions of floating point numbers, modifying digits (in the linked answer, only numbers can be used).

Here's a possible use case:

```py
>>> from basencode import *
>>> n1 = Number(12345)
>> n1.repr_in_base(64) # convert to base 64
'30V'
>>> Number('30V', 64) # construct Integer from base 64
Integer(12345)
>>> n1.repr_in_base(8)
'30071'
>>> n1.repr_in_octal() # shortcuts
'30071'
>>> n1.repr_in_bin() # equivelant to `n1.repr_in_base(2)`
'11000000111001'
>>> n1.repr_in_base(2, digits=list('-+')) # override default digits: use `-` and `+` in place of `0` and `1`
'++------+++--+'
>>> n1.repr_in_base(33) # yet another base - all bases from 2 to 64 are supported from the start
'bb3'
```

How would you add any bases you want? Let me replicate the example of the currently most upvoted answer: the `digits` parameter allows you to override the default digits from base 2 to 64, and provide digits for any base higher than that. The `mode` parameter determines how the value of the representation will determine how (list or string) the answer will be returned.

```py
>>> n2 = Number(67854 ** 15 - 102)
>>> n2.repr_in_base(577, digits=[str(i) for i in range(577)], mode="l")
['4', '473', '131', '96', '431', '285', '524', '486', '28', '23', '16', '82', '292', '538', '149', '25', '41', '483', '100', '517', '131', '28', '0', '435', '197', '264', '455']
>>> n2.repr_in_base(577, mode="l") # the program remembers the digits for base 577 now
['4', '473', '131', '96', '431', '285', '524', '486', '28', '23', '16', '82', '292', '538', '149', '25', '41', '483', '100', '517', '131', '28', '0', '435', '197', '264', '455']
```

Operations can be done: the `Number` class returns an instance of `basencode.Integer` if the provided number is an Integer, else it returns a `basencode.Float`

```
>>> n3 = Number(54321) # the Number class returns an instance of `basencode.Integer` if the provided number is an Integer, otherwise it returns a `basencode.Float`.
>>> n1 + n3
Integer(66666)
>>> n3 - n1
Integer(41976)
>>> n1 * n3
Integer(670592745)
>>> n3 // n1
Integer(4)
>>> n3 / n1 # a basencode.Float class allows conversion of floating point numbers
Float(4.400243013365735)
>>> (n3 / n1).repr_in_base(32)
'4.cpr56v6rnc4oitoblha2r11sus0dheqd4pgechfcjklo74b2bgom7j8ih86mipdvss0068sehi9f3791mdo4uotfujq66cf0jkgo'
>>> n4 = Number(0.5) # returns a basencode.Float
>>> n4.repr_in_bin() # binary version of 0.5
'0.1'
```

**Disclaimer: this project is under active maintenance, and I'm a contributor.**

Answer (score 1):

```
def int2base(a, base, numerals="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
    baseit = lambda a=a, b=base: (not a) and numerals[0]  or baseit(a-a%b,b*base)+numerals[a%b%(base-1) or (a%b) and (base-1)]
    return baseit()
```

---

### explanation

In any base every number is equal to  `a1+a2*base**2+a3*base**3...` The "mission" is to find  all a 's.

For every`N=1,2,3...` the code is isolating the  `aN*base**N` by "mouduling" by b for `b=base**(N+1)`   which slice all a 's bigger than N, and slicing all the a 's that their serial is smaller than N by decreasing a everytime the func is called by the current `aN*base**N` .

Base%(base-1)==1 therefor base**p%(base-1)==1 and therefor q*base^p%(base-1)==q with only one exception when q=base-1 which returns 0.
To fix that in case it returns 0 the func is checking is it 0 from the beggining.

---

### advantages

in this sample theres only one multiplications (instead of division) and some moudulueses which relatively takes small amounts of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import string
>>> def int2base(integer, base):
        if not integer: return '0'
        sign = 1 if integer > 0 else -1
        alphanum = string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase
        nums = alphanum[:base]
        res = ''
        integer *= sign
        while integer:
                integer, mod = divmod(integer, base)
                res += nums[mod]
        return ('' if sign == 1 else '-') + res[::-1]


>>> int2base(-15645, 23)
'-16d5'
>>> int2base(213, 21)
'a3'
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution for those interested. Of course, this will not work with negative binary values. You would need to implement Two's Complement.

```
def generateBase36Alphabet():
    return ''.join([str(i) for i in range(10)]+[chr(i+65) for i in range(26)])

def generateAlphabet(base):
    return generateBase36Alphabet()[:base]

def intToStr(n, base, alphabet):
    def toStr(n, base, alphabet):
        return alphabet[n] if n < base else toStr(n//base,base,alphabet) + alphabet[n%base]
    return ('-' if n < 0 else '') + toStr(abs(n), base, alphabet)

print('{} -> {}'.format(-31, intToStr(-31, 16, generateAlphabet(16)))) # -31 -> -1F
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings aren't the only choice for representing numbers: you can use a list of integers to represent the order of each digit. Those can easily be converted to a string.

None of the answers reject base < 2; and most will run very slowly or crash with stack overflows for *very large* numbers (such as 56789 ** 43210). To avoid such failures, reduce quickly like this:

```
def n_to_base(n, b):
    if b < 2: raise # invalid base
    if abs(n) < b: return [n]
    ret = [y for d in n_to_base(n, b*b) for y in divmod(d, b)]
    return ret[1:] if ret[0] == 0 else ret # remove leading zeros

def base_to_n(v, b):
    h = len(v) // 2
    if h == 0: return v[0]
    return base_to_n(v[:-h], b) * (b**h) + base_to_n(v[-h:], b)

assert ''.join(['0123456789'[x] for x in n_to_base(56789**43210,10)])==str(56789**43210)
```

Speedwise, `n_to_base` is comparable with `str` for large numbers (about 0.3s on my machine), but if you compare against `hex` you may be surprised (about 0.3ms on my machine, or 1000x faster). The reason is because the large integer is stored in memory in base 256 (bytes). Each byte can simply be converted to a two-character hex string. This alignment only happens for bases that are powers of two, which is why there are special cases for 2,8, and 16 (and base64, ascii, utf16, utf32).

Consider the last digit of a decimal string. How does it relate to the sequence of bytes that forms its integer? Let's label the bytes `s[i]` with `s[0]` being the least significant (little endian). Then the last digit is `sum([s[i]*(256**i) % 10 for i in range(n)])`. Well, it happens that 256**i ends with a 6 for i > 0 (6*6=36) so that last digit is `(s[0]*5 + sum(s)*6)%10`. From this, you can see that the last digit depends on the sum of all the bytes. This nonlocal property is what makes converting to decimal harder.

Answer (score 0):

```
def base_changer(number,base):
    buff=97+abs(base-10)
    dic={};buff2='';buff3=10
    for i in range(97,buff+1):
        dic[buff3]=chr(i)
        buff3+=1   
    while(number>=base):
        mod=int(number%base)
        number=int(number//base)
        if (mod) in dic.keys():
            buff2+=dic[mod]
            continue
        buff2+=str(mod)
    if (number) in dic.keys():
        buff2+=dic[number]
    else:
        buff2+=str(number)

    return buff2[::-1]
```

Comment: In this function you can easily convert any decimal number to your favorite base.

Comment: You don't need comment your own answer, you can just edit it to add explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to convert a number of any base to another base.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Test = namedtuple("Test", ["n", "from_base", "to_base", "expected"])


def convert(n: int, from_base: int, to_base: int) -> int:
    digits = []
    while n:
        (n, r) = divmod(n, to_base)
        digits.append(r)    
    return sum(from_base ** i * v for i, v in enumerate(digits))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tests = [
        Test(32, 16, 10, 50),
        Test(32, 20, 10, 62),
        Test(1010, 2, 10, 10),
        Test(8, 10, 8, 10),
        Test(150, 100, 1000, 150),
        Test(1500, 100, 10, 1050000),
    ]

    for test in tests:
        result = convert(*test[:-1])
        assert result == test.expected, f"{test=}, {result=}"
    print("PASSED!!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Say we want to convert 14 to base 2. We repeatedly apply the division algorithm until the quotient is 0:

14 = 2 x 7

7  = 2 x 3 + 1

3 = 2 x 1 + 1

1 = 2 x 0 + 1

The binary representation is just the remainder read from bottom to top. This can be proved by expanding

14 = 2 x 7 = 2 x (2 x 3 + 1) = 2 x (2 x (2 x 1 + 1) + 1) = 2 x (2 x (2 x (2 x 0 + 1) + 1) + 1) = 2^3 + 2^2 + 2

The code is the implementation of the above algorithm.

```
def toBaseX(n, X):
strbin = ""
while n != 0:
    strbin += str(n % X)
    n = n // X
return strbin[::-1]
```

Comment: "They can't go to eleven" -- Nigel from "This is Spinal Tap"

Comment: @MarkBorgerding Yeah. But it should be easy to implement larger bases.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach. At first converting the number then casting it to string.

```py
    def to_base(n, base):
        if base == 10:
            return n
        
        result = 0
        counter = 0
        
        while n:
            r = n % base
            n //= base
            result += r * 10**counter
            counter+=1
        return str(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written this function which I use to encode in different bases. I also provided the way to shift the result by a value 'offset'. This is useful if you'd like to encode to bases above 64, but keeping displayable chars (like a base 95).

I also tried to avoid reversing the output 'list' and tried to minimize computing operations. The array of pow(base) is computed on demand and kept for additional calls to the function.

The output is a binary string

```
pows = {}

######################################################
def encode_base(value,
                base = 10,
                offset = 0) :

    """
    Encode value into a binary string, according to the desired base.

    Input :
        value : Any positive integer value
        offset : Shift the encoding (eg : Starting at chr(32))
        base : The base in which we'd like to encode the value

    Return : Binary string

    Example : with : offset = 32, base = 64

              100 -> !D
              200 -> #(
    """

    # Determine the number of loops
    try :
        pb = pows[base]

    except KeyError :
        pb = pows[base] = {n : base ** n for n in range(0, 8) if n < 2 ** 48 -1}

    for n in pb :
        if value < pb[n] :
            n -= 1
            break

    out = []
    while n + 1 :
        b = pb[n]
        out.append(chr(offset + value // b))
        n -= 1
        value %= b

    return ''.join(out).encode()
```

Answer (score 0):

This function converts any integer from any base to any base

```
def baseconvert(number, srcbase, destbase):
    if srcbase != 10:
        sum = 0
        for _ in range(len(str(number))):
            sum += int(str(number)[_]) * pow(srcbase, len(str(number)) - _ - 1)
        b10 = sum
        return baseconvert(b10, 10, destbase)
    end = ''
    q = number
    while(True):
        r = q % destbase
        q = q // destbase
        end = str(r) + end
        if(q<destbase):
            end = str(q) + end
            return int(end)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below provided Python code converts a Python integer to a string in arbitrary base ( from 2 up to infinity ) and works in both directions. So all the created strings can be converted back to Python integers by providing a string for N instead of an integer.
The code works only on positive numbers by intention (there is in my eyes some hassle about negative values and their bit representations I don't want to dig into). Just pick from this code what you need, want or like, or just have fun learning about available options. Much is there only for the purpose of documenting all the various available approaches ( e.g. the Oneliner seems not to be fast, even if promised to be ).

I like the by Salvador Dali proposed format for infinite large bases. A nice proposal which works optically well even for simple binary bit representations. Notice that the width=x padding parameter in case of infiniteBase=True formatted string applies to the digits and not to the whole number. It seems, that code handling infiniteBase digits format runs even a bit faster than the other options - another reason for using it?

I don't like the idea of using Unicode for extending the number of symbols available for digits, so don't look in the code below for it, because it's not there. Use the proposed infiniteBase format instead or store integers as bytes for compression purposes.

```
    def inumToStr( N, base=2, width=1, infiniteBase=False,\
    useNumpy=False, useRecursion=False, useOneliner=False, \
    useGmpy=False, verbose=True):
    ''' Positive numbers only, but works in BOTH directions.
    For strings in infiniteBase notation set for bases <= 62 
    infiniteBase=True . Examples of use:
    inumToStr( 17,  2, 1, 1)             # [1,0,0,0,1]
    inumToStr( 17,  3, 5)                #       00122
    inumToStr(245, 16, 4)                #        00F5
    inumToStr(245, 36, 4,0,1)            #        006T
    inumToStr(245245245245,36,10,0,1)    #  0034NWOQBH
    inumToStr(245245245245,62)           #     4JhA3Th 
        245245245245 == int(gmpy2.mpz('4JhA3Th',62))
    inumToStr(245245245245,99,2) # [25,78, 5,23,70,44]
    ----------------------------------------------------
    inumToStr( '[1,0,0,0,1]',2, infiniteBase=True ) # 17 
    inumToStr( '[25,78, 5,23,70,44]', 99) # 245245245245
    inumToStr( '0034NWOQBH', 36 )         # 245245245245 
    inumToStr( '4JhA3Th'   , 62 )         # 245245245245
    ----------------------------------------------------
    --- Timings for N = 2**4096, base=36: 
                                      standard: 0.0023
                                      infinite: 0.0017
                                      numpy   : 0.1277
                                      recursio; 0.0022
                                      oneliner: 0.0146
                For N = 2**8192: 
                                      standard: 0.0075
                                      infinite: 0.0053
                                      numpy   : 0.1369
    max. recursion depth exceeded:    recursio/oneliner
    '''
    show = print
    if type(N) is str and ( infiniteBase is True or base > 62 ):
        lstN = eval(N)
        if verbose: show(' converting a non-standard infiniteBase bits string to Python integer')
        return sum( [ item*base**pow for pow, item in enumerate(lstN[::-1]) ] )
    if type(N) is str and base <= 36:
        if verbose: show('base <= 36. Returning Python int(N, base)')
        return int(N, base)
    if type(N) is str and base <= 62:
        if useGmpy: 
            if verbose: show(' base <= 62, useGmpy=True, returning int(gmpy2.mpz(N,base))')
            return int(gmpy2.mpz(N,base))
        else:
            if verbose: show(' base <= 62, useGmpy=False, self-calculating return value)')
            lstStrOfDigits="0123456789"+ \
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".upper() + \
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            dictCharToPow = {}
            for index, char in enumerate(lstStrOfDigits):
                dictCharToPow.update({char : index}) 
            return sum( dictCharToPow[item]*base**pow for pow, item in enumerate(N[::-1]) )
        #:if
    #:if        
        
    if useOneliner and base <= 36:  
        if verbose: show(' base <= 36, useOneliner=True, running the Oneliner code')
        d="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        baseit = lambda a=N, b=base: (not a) and d[0]  or \
        baseit(a-a%b,b*base)+d[a%b%(base-1) or (a%b) and (base-1)]
        return baseit().rjust(width, d[0])[1:]

    if useRecursion and base <= 36: 
        if verbose: show(' base <= 36, useRecursion=True, running recursion algorythm')
        BS="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        def to_base(n, b): 
            return "0" if not n else to_base(n//b, b).lstrip("0") + BS[n%b]
        return to_base(N, base).rjust(width,BS[0])
        
    if base > 62 or infiniteBase:
        if verbose: show(' base > 62 or infiniteBase=True, returning a non-standard digits string')
        # Allows arbitrary large base with 'width=...' 
        # applied to each digit (useful also for bits )
        N, digit = divmod(N, base)
        strN = str(digit).rjust(width, ' ')+']'
        while N:
            N, digit = divmod(N, base)
            strN = str(digit).rjust(width, ' ') + ',' + strN
        return '[' + strN
    #:if        
    
    if base == 2:
        if verbose: show(" base = 2, returning Python str(f'{N:0{width}b}')")
        return str(f'{N:0{width}b}')
    if base == 8:
        if verbose: show(" base = 8, returning Python str(f'{N:0{width}o}')")
        return str(f'{N:0{width}o}')
    if base == 16:
        if verbose: show(" base = 16, returning Python str(f'{N:0{width}X}')")
        return str(f'{N:0{width}X}')

    if base <= 36:
        if useNumpy: 
            if verbose: show(" base <= 36, useNumpy=True, returning np.base_repr(N, base)")
            import numpy as np
            strN = np.base_repr(N, base)
            return strN.rjust(width, '0') 
        else:
            if verbose: show(' base <= 36, useNumpy=False, self-calculating return value)')
            lstStrOfDigits="0123456789"+"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".upper()
            strN = lstStrOfDigits[N % base] # rightmost digit
            while N >= base:
                N //= base # consume already converted digit
                strN = lstStrOfDigits[N % base] + strN # add digits to the left
            #:while
            return strN.rjust(width, lstStrOfDigits[0])
        #:if
    #:if
    
    if base <= 62:
        if useGmpy: 
            if verbose: show(" base <= 62, useGmpy=True, returning gmpy2.digits(N, base)")
            import gmpy2
            strN = gmpy2.digits(N, base)
            return strN.rjust(width, '0') 
            # back to Python int from gmpy2.mpz with 
            #     int(gmpy2.mpz('4JhA3Th',62))
        else:
            if verbose: show(' base <= 62, useGmpy=False, self-calculating return value)')
            lstStrOfDigits= "0123456789" + \
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".upper() + \
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            strN = lstStrOfDigits[N % base] # rightmost digit
            while N >= base:
                N //= base # consume already converted digit
                strN = lstStrOfDigits[N % base] + strN # add digits to the left
            #:while
            return strN.rjust(width, lstStrOfDigits[0])
        #:if
    #:if    
#:def
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm presenting a "unoptimized" solution for bases between 2 and 9:

```py
  def to_base(N, base=2):
    N_in_base = ''
    while True:
        N_in_base = str(N % base) + N_in_base
        N //= base
        if N == 0:
            break
    return N_in_base
```

This solution does not require reversing the final result, but it's actually not optimized. Refer to this answer to see why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37133870/7896998

Answer (score 0):

**Simple base transformation**

```
def int_to_str(x, b):
    s = ""
    while x:
        s = str(x % b) + s
        x //= b
    return s
```

**Example of output with no 0 to base 9**

```
s = ""
x = int(input())
while x:
    if x % 9 == 0:
        s = "9" + s
        x -= x % 10
        x = x // 9
    else:
        s = str(x % 9) + s
        x = x // 9

print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I wrote to help someone who was looking to [Speedily calculate base 3 value of real huge integer number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53642569/5987).  It turns out the way to do that is to make a function that works with any base and have it call itself recursively.  This takes advantage of a few properties:

- Python can work with integers of unlimited size and perform all the usual arithmetic operations on them.
- Converting from `base**2` to `base` is easy, because each digit in `base**2` becomes two digits in `base` using a simple division and remainder.
- If the base is larger than the number you're trying to convert, the answer is trivial - the number is the single digit.

```
def number_to_base(n, base):
    if n < base:
        return [n]
    else:
        digits = [d for x in number_to_base(n, base*base) for d in divmod(x, base)]
        return digits if digits[0] else digits[1:]
```

This returns a list of numeric digits.  To convert it to a string that can be interpreted by `int(s, base)` is quite simple:

```
def int2base(x, base, alphabet='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'):
    return ''.join(alphabet[digit] for digit in number_to_base(x, base))
```

This only handles positive numbers, but making it handle negative numbers is trivial - I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

This function is actually faster than Python's `str()` function for base 10 if the number is large enough.  In my tests they were equal at about 100000 digits.

Answer (score -1):

```
def dec_to_radix(input, to_radix=2, power=None):
    if not isinstance(input, int):
        raise TypeError('Not an integer!')
    elif power is None:
        power = 1

    if input == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        remainder = input % to_radix**power
        digit = str(int(remainder/to_radix**(power-1)))
        return int(str(dec_to_radix(input-remainder, to_radix, power+1)) + digit)

def radix_to_dec(input, from_radix):
    if not isinstance(input, int):
        raise TypeError('Not an integer!')
    return sum(int(digit)*(from_radix**power) for power, digit in enumerate(str(input)[::-1]))

def radix_to_radix(input, from_radix=10, to_radix=2, power=None):
    dec = radix_to_dec(input, from_radix)
    return dec_to_radix(dec, to_radix, power)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def baseConverter(x, b):
    s = ""
    d = string.printable.upper()
    while x > 0:
        s += d[x%b]
        x = x / b
    return s[::-1]
```

Comment: For python3 your code does this:

baseConverter(0, 26) -> ''
baseConverter(1, 26) -> '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'

For python2 it does this:

baseConverter(0, 26) -> ''
baseConverter(1, 26) -> 1
baseConverter(3, 26) -> 3
baseConverter(5, 26) -> 5
baseConverter(26, 26) -> 10
baseConverter(32, 26) -> 16

Answer (score -1):

Another short one (and easier to understand imo):

```
def int_to_str(n, b, symbols='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'):
    return (int_to_str(n/b, b, symbols) if n >= b else "") + symbols[n%b]
```

And with proper exception handling:

```
def int_to_str(n, b, symbols='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'):
    try:
        return (int_to_str(n/b, b) if n >= b else "") + symbols[n%b]
    except IndexError:
        raise ValueError(
            "The symbols provided are not enough to represent this number in "
            "this base")
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a recursive version that handles signed integers and custom digits.

```
import string

def base_convert(x, base, digits=None):
    """Convert integer `x` from base 10 to base `base` using `digits` characters as digits.
    If `digits` is omitted, it will use decimal digits + lowercase letters + uppercase letters.
    """
    digits = digits or (string.digits + string.ascii_letters)
    assert 2 <= base <= len(digits), "Unsupported base: {}".format(base)
    if x == 0:
        return digits[0]
    sign = '-' if x < 0 else ''
    x = abs(x)
    first_digits = base_convert(x // base, base, digits).lstrip(digits[0])
    return sign + first_digits + digits[x % base]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
num = input("number")
power = 0
num = int(num)
while num > 10:
    num = num / 10
    power += 1

print(str(round(num, 2)) + "^" + str(power))
```

Comment: please add some brief information that what you did special init

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Well I personally use this function, written by me

```
import string

def to_base(value, base, digits=string.digits+string.ascii_letters):    # converts decimal to base n

    digits_slice = digits[0:base]

    temporary_var = value
    data = [temporary_var]

    while True:
        temporary_var = temporary_var // base
        data.append(temporary_var)
        if temporary_var < base:
            break

    result = ''
    for each_data in data:
        result += digits_slice[each_data % base]
    result = result[::-1]

    return result
```

This is how you can use it

`print(to_base(7, base=2))`

Output:
`"111"`

`print(to_base(23, base=3))`

Output:
`"212"`

Please feel free to suggest improvements in my code.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question but I thought i'd share my take on it as I feel it is somewhat simpler that other answers (good for bases from 2 to 36):

```
def intStr(n,base=10):
    if n < 0   : return "-" + intStr(-n,base)         # handle negatives
    if n < base: return chr([48,55][n>9] + n)         # 48 => "0"..., 65 => "A"...
    return intStr(n//base,base) + intStr(n%base,base) # recurse for multiple digits
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old post, but I'm just leaving my solution here just in case.

```
def decimal_to_given_base(integer_to_convert, base):
     remainder = integer_to_convert // base
     digit = integer_to_convert % base
     if integer_to_convert == 0:
         return '0'
     elif remainder == 0:
         return str(digit)
     else:
         return decimal_to_given_base(remainder, base) + str(digit)
```

Answer (score -1):

I made my function to do this. Run well on windows 10, python 3.7.3.

```
def number_to_base(number, base, precision = 10):
    if number == 0:
        return [0]
    
    positive = number >= 0
    number = abs(number)
    
    ints = []  # store the integer bases
    floats = []  # store the floating bases

    float_point = number % 1
    number = int(number)
    while number:
        ints.append(int(number%base))
        number //= base
    ints.reverse()
    
    while float_point and precision:
        precision -= 1
        float_point *= base
        floats.append(int(float_point))
        float_point = float_point - int(float_point)

    return ints, floats, positive


def base_to_str(bases, string="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"):
    """bases is a two dimension list, where bases[0] contains a list of the integers,
    and bases[1] contains a list of the floating numbers, bases[2] is a boolean, that's
    true when it's a positive number
    """
    ints = []
    floats = []

    for i in bases[0]:
        ints.append(string[i])

    for i in bases[1]:
        floats.append(string[i])

    if len(bases[1]) > 0:
        return (["-", ""][bases[2]] + "".join(ints)) + "." + ("".join(floats))
    else:
        return (["-", ""][bases[2]] + "".join(ints))
```

Example:

```
>>> base_to_str(number_to_base(-6.252, 2))
'-110.0100000010'
```