# Python: Is it possible to download ENTIRE web page in PhantomJS

Tags: python-3.x, phantomjs

I have used PhantomJS for scraping purpose. I would like to know about possibility of download all contents of a URL(inclduing Images, CSS and JS) and save locally for browsing?

Comment: do you have wget installed ?

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver #for cookies collections after all AJAX/JS being executed
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 Safari/537.36")

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap, service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any', '--web-security=false'])
driver.set_window_size(1366,768)

driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')

driver.page_source
```

This is complete code that uses Python Selenium + PhantomJS and at the end you have complete page source.

Comment: I said entire page including assets. Question updated

Comment: I dont know of that. :( Maybe you have to iterate over all <script> tags and then load those files and then save it on your server.

Comment: I know this'd be last resort, was wondering if some library already exist.

Comment: You won't be able to download files with just PhantomJs, the addition to file download support has been requested for ages, but they desn't seem to care. All that said, @Umair aproach could be usefull, with bf4 you could get whatever elements you want and then dowload them using request.

Answer (score 0):

we can use evaluate() function to get the content. I use this in nodejs.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://google.com', function(status) {

  var title = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.title;
  });

  console.log(title);
  phantom.exit();

});`
```

Comment: Well, is it Python?

Comment: No dude. Its nodejs. @volatil3

Comment: [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753878/how-to-evaluate-javascript-code-in-python). You can check this link.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of wget being installed, this task is rather easy:

```
domain = "www.google.de"
from subprocess import call
call(["wget", "-mk", domain])
```