# Python: Integer to Base 32 hex (aka. Triacontakaidecimal)

Tags: python, integer, hex, base32

Ok so going from Base 32 hex (aka. Triacontakaidecimal) to integer is pretty easy for example:

```
>>>int("v", 32)
31
```

How do you do it the other way around however? I was thinking of setting up a dictionary if a method doesn't exist to do so.

EDIT:

I actually got this working with the dictionary, the idea of my this method was to take a base 32 hex character and increment it if the LSB wasn't set to 1

```
>>> def incHex(hexChar):
...     intRep = int(hexChar, 32)
...     binRep = bin(intRep)
...     if(binRep[-1:]!='1'):
...         intRep += 1
...     convDict = {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,10:'A',11:'B',12:'C',
...                 13:'D',14:'E',15:'F',16:'G',17:'H',18:'I',19:'J',20:'K',21:'L',
...                 22:'M',23:'N',24:'O',25:'P',26:'Q',27:'R',28:'S',29:'T',30:'U',
...                 31:'V'}
...     return convDict[intRep]
...
>>> incHex('l')
'L'
>>> incHex('m')
'N'
>>>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert integer to a string in a given numeric base in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/convert-integer-to-a-string-in-a-given-numeric-base-in-python)

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python

Comment: Actually the first link is probably too far, and the second link is a misunderstanding, I don't want to go from hex to integer, I want to go from integer to base 32 hex. I've updated my OP as it works and is what I want.

Comment: Hex is "hexadecimal" which is base 16.  Only 16.  "Base 32 hex" doesn't mean anything.  Please fix the question to remove the phrase "base 32 hex", since it can't mean anything.

Comment: Actually it does exist http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32#base32hex, but it's called Triacontakaidecimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dictionary is probably a little bit of overkill for what you want to do. Why not just use a tuple:

```
convTable = ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V')
```

That will make lookups faster while saving you memory as well.

If you are just looking up integers in the range 0-31 then you can just do:

```
getHex32Rep(val):
    return convTable[val]
```

Also, you probably want to do:

```
if(binRep[-1]!='1'):
```

instead of

```
if(binRep[-1:]!='1'):
```

Comment: Good points, what difference is there between binRep[-1] and binRep[-1:]?

Comment: `binRep[-1]` returns the last element of `binRep`. `binRep[-1]` Returns a list containing only the last element of `binRep`, because the `:` operator creates a list slice, as opposed to accessing an element of the array.

Comment: It will work similarly well with just a string instead of tuple: `convTable = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV'`

Answer (score 2):

another way to make the convDict

```
>>> import string
>>> convDict = {c:int(c,32) for c in (string.digits+string.ascii_lowercase)[:32]}
>>> convDict
{'1': 1, '0': 0, '3': 3, '2': 2, '5': 5, '4': 4, '7': 7, '6': 6, '9': 9, '8': 8, 'a': 10, 'c': 12, 'b': 11, 'e': 14, 'd': 13, 'g': 16, 'f': 15, 'i': 18, 'h': 17, 'k': 20, 'j': 19, 'm': 22, 'l': 21, 'o': 24, 'n': 23, 'q': 26, 'p': 25, 's': 28, 'r': 27, 'u': 30, 't': 29, 'v': 31}
```

Comment: Is this syntax (`{key:val for key in iterable}`) only available in a particular version of Python? I get a syntax error in Python 2.6.

Comment: @Christopher, yes it's 2.7+. In 2.6 the equivalent is `dict((c,int(c,32)) for c in (string.digits+string.ascii_lowercase)[:32])`

Answer (score 1):

I found the [numconv](https://tabo.pe/projects/numconv/docs/2.1.1/) package, which seems to provide this?

Answer (score 0):

A decade later, (January 2021)

I found the following package:

https://pypi.org/project/base32-crockford/

> base32-crockford
>
> A Python module implementing the alternate base32 encoding as
> described by Douglas Crockford at:
> http://www.crockford.com/wrmg/base32.html.
>
> He designed the encoding to:
>
> ```
>     Be human and machine readable
>     Be compact
>     Be error resistant
>     Be pronounceable
> ```
>
> It uses a symbol set of 10 digits and 22 letters, excluding I, L O and
> U. Decoding is not case sensitive, and 'i' and 'l' are converted to
> '1' and 'o' is converted to '0'. Encoding uses only upper-case
> characters.
>
> Hyphens may be present in symbol strings to improve readability, and
> are removed when decoding.
>
> A check symbol can be appended to a symbol string to detect errors
> within the string.

Comment: bad choice, by removing `ILOU`  make the result not always compatible with the standard library

Comment: @ui  That is dependent on the use-case, is it not?