# Faster and if possible less memory cost method generate an alphanumeric code?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a really simple short URL redirect without a database.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['file'];
$name = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", '', $name);
$file = 'data/' . $name;

// File found
if (is_file($file))
{
    // Read the first line, we don't use file_get_contents as the data folder is protected and must be read internally
    $f = fopen($file, 'r');
    $data = fgets($f);
    fclose($f);

    // Redirect to the real URL
    header("Location: $data");
}
else
{
    // What a shame the URL does not exist
    header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com/");
}

exit();
?>
```

- **I would like to know what would be the faster and if
  possible less memory cost method to generate an alphanumeric code from
  6 to 8 characters that does not collide with the existent ones in the
  data folder ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a requirement also that for any given url it must be possible to look up the short code for it? A system of just counting up numbers would do the trick to just generate unique filenames but of course this is not a repeatable method so if the same url went in multiple times it would come out with different keys each time.

If this is acceptable then I'd just suggest a counter, possibly in base 36 (case insensitive alphanumeric) or similar to give you maximum key space size. You could have one file that contains the current count (could also be stored in memory but would need to be reloaded on restart) and then of course you have to be careful about multi-thread access both reading the next value at the same time.

If you need a given url to be consistently given the same id then you could have a second directory storing files named after the url (escaped as appropriate) containing the key that you generated the first time for them. When generating new keys you can look up in this file directory for if the url already has a key and return that if it is there.

As you can see this is basically crudely replicating the way the database will work with the two directories basically being indexes on a table of url and key.

The only other way I can think to do it would be to have some function that is one-to-one that will be guaranteed for the input you are looking at to generate a string under a certain length. I can't think where you would find such a function. Compression algorithms are the closest thing but they of course generate output that is unlikely to suit your need (since the binary it compresses to will probably as big as the original string once it has been base64 encoded or similar)

A hashing function as suggested by fardjad will probably be alright but there is no way to go from a hashed value back to the url and there is no guarantee that two inputs will be unique (though the chances of them not being so are extremely small).

I suspect fardjad's solution will be as good as you need in practice but it depends how robust this needs to be.

I should note finally that I have never written or looked much into the shorter url services so none of what I say is expert advice, just thoughts on how I would do it if it were me having done no research. :)

Comment: I don't need to reference the code back to the URL no, but I would like it to be alphanumeric, I don't think it will ever use all combinations possible with 8 characters it is basic for internal usage, there will be no creation of short URL at the same given time, it is not a system open to public just one person will be controlling all the signed short URLs. This is mainly why I am looking into what would be the fastest way to generate the alphanumeric code against matching it with the existent files name in the data DIR, it is nothing fancy like I initially said just want to keep resources

Comment: at minimum usage while still having it to process as fast as possible, Initially we will have a total of 90000 entries.

Comment: a single directory with so many files will result in performance issues I think. Consider subdirectories or put the mapping into a file and read it into memory.

Comment: Quite right, @qingbo. I was mainly considering the naem generation side of the problem but as you say you might be best off having a name of abcdefgh stored as a/b/c/defgh or something like that. Exact number of levels of subdirectories depends probably on your expected usage and possibly even on your FS.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you want to generate an alpha-numeric code for each new file being added to data folder and the content of those files is where you want to redirect to.

The method you're using looks good to me. Just a few suggestions:

You could use the `$name` MD5 hash to name files in data folder so you won't need to remove non-alphabetic characters in this line:

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", '', $name);
```

just calculate the hash to get file names instead:

```
file_name = md5($name);
```

also the file names will be unique this way.

Another suggestion is to use a XML file to store redirects if you really don't want to use databases. It can be done easily by using [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)(Take a look at the examples).

Comment: `the file names will be unique this way` - I think you mean that the filenames will almost certainly be unique but have a very small chance of not being so. Its probably not going to be a problem but its worth being clear. :)

Comment: `preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", '', $name);` is intent just to ensure the domain slash will be correct and i wish to keep the names shorter at an max of 6 to 8 characters so how converting the url to md5 would help me if I still need to figure out the way to generate each short code as asked in the question ?

Comment: @Guapo, as you decrease the hash length, no matter what hashing algorithm you use, the collision rate increases, what you can do is check if the generated name is already exists and generate another code if so, or alternatively you can use some thing like a counter as $name.

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention in my answer is `tempnam()` function. It get the directory name and generates a unique file name with a prefix.

Comment: @fardjad is, in this case the only option a while until it finds an available file name ? Would uniqueid work out together with substr in this case or even mt_rand or it would be a good option to keep producing the codes what would be a good option ? While I think md5 would work out well I have a lot of doubts if it would be a good option regarding the limitation I have set for the codes to be from 6 to 8 characters long.

Comment: As I said before there are two approaches to this problem,
1. Using an increasing identifier (something like a counter but mixed with alphabetic symbols, ex. a number represented in base 36 as Chris explained in his answer) 2. Using a hashing algorithm or a random string generator in a `do { $generated_name = generate_new_name(); } while { is_file($generated_name); }`. And in terms of speed, the first approach would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct your pasted code is the url redirect logic, not file name generation, right? I suggest you use a single threaded process (for example, a [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) server) to generate and maintain a `max_number` value.

Each time you need a new file name, just send a request to that server. The server increments the `max_number` and returns its current value. Then in your PHP code, convert this integer to a string consisting of alphanumeric characters. The PHP [gmp_strval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-strval.php) function can do this job by converting a number to base-62 form.

This way is safe since it guarantees absolute uniqueness in a simple way. And I guess it's a common approach which was used by many public url shortner services as I noticed that their strings increment naturally.

Of course the `gmp_strval` function can be implemented in your own code easily if it's not available on your machine. Some examples here: [How to convert an integer in any base to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/convert-integer-to-a-string-in-a-given-numeric-base-in-python)

Shorter is better for this kind of service. But if you do want 6-8 characters, just start with base-62 string "100000" (916132832 in decimal form).

Comment: `If I'm correct your pasted code is the url redirect logic, not file name generation, right?` yes ! `gmp_strval` seems like a interesting option I will give it a try to see how it works if it is available in the host we have.