# list of arbitrary-base digits to int

Tags: python, list, int, radix

Given a `list` of integers representing the digits of a number in base `b`, how do I convert this `list` to an `int` for any `b` most efficiently?

```
numlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def list2int(numList, b):
    if b == 10: return int(''.join(map(str, numList)))
    else: ?

print list2int(numList, 7)
>>> 3267
```

I can only think of the naive approach to do this but this scales really horribly.

```
def list2int(numList, b):
    num = 0
    for i, ii in enumerate(numList): num += ii * b**(len(numList) - i - 1)
    return num
```

Are there any better ways?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/convert-integer-to-a-string-in-a-given-numeric-base-in-python

Comment: @mockinterface: that looks like the opposite of what the OP is trying to do...

Comment: how do you define the representation of a number in an arbitrary base (especially if the base is > 10) on digits ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `reduce`:

```
In [3]: reduce(lambda x,y:7*x+y, numlist)
Out[3]: 3267
```

where `7` is the base.

Comment: very interesting. I like answer very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the base to `int()`, but this will work only up to base 36:

```
>>> int(''.join(map(str, numlist)), 7)
3267
>>> int(''.join(map(str, numlist)), 15)
58115
>>> int(''.join(map(str, numlist)), 36)
1776965
```

Comment: Considering you can't represent the digits of a base higher than 10 as single-digit `int`s to begin with, only going up to base 36 is hardly a problem :)

Comment: And what do single-digit ints have to do with the question? His input is a list of arbitrary integer coefficients.