# Happy numbers using python base 8

Tags: python

I have written a code that works for base 10

 How to make it work for base 8??

```
SQUARE = dict([(c, int(c)**2) for c in "0123456789"])
def is_happy(n):
 s = set()
 while (n > 1) and (n not in s):
   s.add(n)
   n = sum(SQUARE[d] for d in str(n))
 return n == 1

a=is_happy(28)
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: @thefourtheye He's probably trying to find these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number

Comment: Really, did you write that code?  Or did you copy it from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number#Programming_example)?

Comment: @devnull  He's clearly a ***hacker***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to replace all the places in the algorithm where "base-10" is used with base 8. The only place this really is is when we turn the number into a string, so we can square each "digit". To determine digits, we need a base. Normally, we choose base 10, as your sample shows. [Converting an integer to a string in an arbitrary base (or, in your case 8) has been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/convert-integer-to-a-string-in-a-given-numeric-base-in-python).

We might also adjust the lookup table `SQUARE`.

```
def to_base_8(n):
    digits = []
    while n > 0:
        digits.append(str(n % 8))
        n = n // 8
    return ''.join(reversed(digits))

SQUARE = dict([(c, int(c)**2) for c in "01234567"])
def is_happy(n):
 s = set()
 while (n > 1) and (n not in s):
   s.add(n)
   n = sum(SQUARE[d] for d in to_base_8(n))
 return n == 1

a=is_happy(28)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the octal representation instead.

```
n = sum(SQUARE[d] for d in oct(n))
```