# What is the best way to convert raw binary data to a custom base in python?

Tags: python, binary, int, radix

I need to convert some data to base 29 before processing and I'm using this:

```
import string

def datatobase(data, base):
    digs = string.digits + string.lowercase + string.uppercase
    if base > len(digs):
        return None
    digits = []
    x = int(data.encode("hex"), 16)
    while x:
        digits.append(digs[x % base])
        x /= base
    digits.reverse()
    return ''.join(digits)
```

Problem is that this small code is slowing my program too much so what would you do to replace it?

A custom answer for base 29 only would be great too!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/convert-integer-to-a-string-in-a-given-numeric-base-in-python.

Comment: If you want to do this quickly, like in linear time, then I believe you need to change your target base to something that is a power of 2, like 32 or 16.

Comment: Please show an example of the ```data``` you are trying to convert.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question, I've read the page bitsplit: is pointing before posting but here I have a real performance issue :)
Antom wwii: The data I'm converting doesn't matter and I also made a previous version of my script using power of 2 (and yes this is obviously much faster). I really need using base 29 conversion now.

Answer (score 0):

Base 29, only, solution for an `int` argument.

Recursive:

```
s = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS'
def foo(n, s=s):
    if n < 29:
        return s[n]
    a, b = divmod(n, 29)
    return foo(a) + s[b]
```

*Regular*:

```
def foo(n, s=s):    
    x = ''
    while n >= 29:
        n, b = divmod(n, 29)
        x += s[b]
    x += s[n]
    return x[::-1]
```

Comment: Isn't this basically the same algorithm as OP's?

Comment: @Anton - basically the same, however, this answer includes some bugs that the OP's algorithm doesn't :) 1) base 29 symbols range from `0-9` and `A-S`, and 2) the maximum decimal value for a single "digit" in base 29 is 28, not 29.

Comment: @Anton I took OP's problem as a performance issue - I tried to improve the performance but I didn't compare it. Bugs fixed, thnx

Answer (score 0):

If you take care of runtime... This version is 2.8 times faster then yours and 7% faster then @wwii.

```
def bin2base29(n):
    s = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS'
    return s[n] if n < 29 else bin2base29(n / 29) + s[n % 29]
```

Here is my final iterative and fastest solution of my approaches adapted from @wwii.

```
def bin2base29(n):
    s = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS'
    x = ''
    while n > 0:
        x = s[n % 29] + x
        n /= 29
    return x
```

Comment: `s` is too short - it is missing the `S`. Also, maximum `n` for single digit in base 29 is 28, not 29.

Comment: @mhawke Thanks you are right. My examples did all work, tried it with 28,29 now... :)

Comment: How did you measure your algorithm's performance? It's not 29 times faster than the OP's (besides, "29" seems a little coincidental!)

Comment: @mhawke Thank you for your tenacity. I think I mixed the repeats in timeit or used to few repetitions. I correct it and it seems also more realistic to me now. Do you get similar numbers?

Comment: Actually, I found the OP's to be the fastest. Your's, mine, and wwii's iterative one are very similar.

Comment: @mhawke not for me. As a reference I use datatobase('2347878234', 62) and 100000 times.

Comment: @wenzul - my edits seem to make them more competitive.

Comment: @wwii In the first try I thought mine is more then 7% faster, now yours is almost equal. It also depends on the length of the input. The longer it will be the faster the iteration version will be. You could simple improve yours by avoiding `divmod` or hold the reference in a local variable. There is also an error in your paste. I will correct it. Now you beat the recursive version.

Comment: `hold the reference in a local variable` - please explain.  Both versions appear competitive with yours despite using `divmod` - please explain why avoiding `divmod` would help.

Comment: @wwii If you store `dm = divmod` once in a local variable (in the iterative case) you can save the lookup for the built-in function each loop cycle. Because reading local variables is actually faster than lookups for global ones. And calling a function in a loop is also more expensive than using the arithmetic operations. You can read about that [here](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/).

Comment: So, if the function definition includes a default argument for a resource, that resource is *placed* in the function's local scope when the function is initially *interpreted* and that should have a slight performance improvement? ... I get about 2% converting a number that takes twenty iterations.  ```divmod``` iterative versions are still beating your non-```divmod``` version - maybe calling a ```built-in``` isn't very expensive.  Mine has three operations in the loop and yours has five...

Comment: @wwii I didn't get your point. It not depends on a default argument. Fixed arguments will be passed to a function like others. Try `python -m timeit "n=10/2;r=10%2"`, `python -m timeit "n,r = divmod(10,2)"` and `python -m timeit -s "dm=divmod" "n,r = dm(10,2)"` as an approximate comparison. If you are inside a function the lookup for built-ins will take more time than already in the globals like here. _10000000 loops: 0.0486 / 0.178 / 0.162 usec per loop_. It greatly depends on the loop count and length of input respectively. If this won't satisfy please give your test cases.

Comment: I meant: ```def foo(n, s=s, dm = divmod):```

Comment: @wwii No, default arguments are also slower than just leave it out and define it local. I meant `def foo(n): s = ...; dm = divmod; while...`. There is an example [here](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/)...

Comment: @wwii Confusing. Actually, for me bin2base29 with exactly your code paste is the fastest also. Windows Python 2.7.6 64 Bit. `v1 4.94157717086, v2 4.86761055184, v3 4.89439396469, bin2base29 4.75006779537`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not averse to using a third-party package, `numpy.base_repr()` is a very convenient way to do your conversions:

```
import os
import numpy

def datatobase(data, base):
    n = int(data.encode('hex'), 16)
    return numpy.base_repr(n, base)

>>> data = os.urandom(32)
>>> data
'\xfcBs\x82\xa8&\x18\xaaK\x8c$\x0fZ\x95\xc0aA%\x93\x91\xcc\x8a\xa8\xfdbk\xeb\x14\x15\x06\xbag'

>>> datatobase(data, 29)
'A8FB42CHLNEIOOE75AG773EKGBA69QP89PANAF8ROH2GA1LF3CC5H'
>>> datatobase(data, 16)
'FC427382A82618AA4B8C240F5A95C06141259391CC8AA8FD626BEB141506BA67'
```

You'd need to profile to see whether this provides adequate performance for your application.

**Update**

Profiling shows that `numpy.base_repr()` is slower than the OP's implementation. This is because the numpy implementation is basically the same algorithm implemented in Python, with the addition of optional zero padding.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to edit my question because this is what I'm doing now. Gonna profiling soon to see if it's really better or not.

Comment: It's 40% worse than the iterative one.

Comment: @wenzul:  The timings are greatly affected by the length of the binary string. On short strings your iterative algorithm is much faster, on longer strings (e.g. 256 bytes) it's actually slower. I find the OP's algorithm to be the fastest in most cases. One other thing, probably you are not including the cost of the conversion from a string of binary data to an int - this is worth approx 7% on a short string?