# Python: breaking down integers into exponents?

Tags: python, radix

I would like to make a function which convert an integer into exponents of base 27. The function should return a list with the multiple of the largest exponent in the first position and the final exponent in the last. So for example, 65 would return [2,11]. I've tried using int % b, where b is an increasing power of 27 within a loop. However it's turning out very complicated. Any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/convert-integer-to-a-string-in-a-given-numeric-base-in-python

Comment: You're not seeking *exponents*. You're seeking *coefficients*. Namely, coefficients to be multiplied by successive powers of 27. You already know the exponents, which for the list in your example would be 1 and 0, respectively.

Comment: @tobias, yes and not into letters

Comment: @idjaw, ok but It seems over complicated and unnecessarily long and inefficient, so I didn't think it would help (i'm a beginner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def convert(x, base):
  res = []
  while x:
    res.append(x%base)
    x //= base # this line depends on Python's version!
  res.reverse()
  return res
```

Comment: You can use `x, r = divmod(x, base)` to do both integer division and modulo in one step, then append `r`

Comment: The `x //= base` line should be fine in any (non-ancient) Python version.

Comment: @tobias_k: Sadly, unless the numbers in question are huge, using `divmod` is almost always slower, because looking up and explicitly calling builtin functions has enormous overhead (at least in CPython), such that doing the same work with syntax is usually faster. For `x` below a hundred bits (give or take, depending on `base`), `q, r = x // base, x % base` is faster than `q, r = divmod(x, base)`, which sounds ridiculous, but this is Python, and performance doesn't have to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def base_27(num):
    if num == 0:
        return []
    q, r = divmod(num, 27)
    result = base_27(q)
    result.append(r)
    return result
```

Comment: Nice, but could be shorter: `return base_27(num // 27) + [num % 27] if num else []`

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks. I barely know Python but I'm learning it to try to get the generalist badge. Is anything other than 0 basically true?

Comment: Not everything. What evaluates to false are things like 0, empty string, empty collection, None, etc.; most other things evaluate to true.