# Time complexity of string concatenation in Python

Tags: python, string, time-complexity

I'm analysing the complexity of my code.
From what I found online, since strings are immutable in python, a concatenation of a string and a character should be O(len(string) + 1).

Now, here is my piece of code (simplified):

```
word = ""
for i in range(m):
    word = char_value + word
return word
```

The total time complexity should be:

*(0+1) + (1+1) +...+ m = m(m+1)/2 = O(m^2)*

Is this correct?

Comment: What do you count: walclock time, number of operations? I doubt that concatenation of `m` strings is quadratic in `m`.

Comment: Number of operations, e.g. allocating a string of n characters should take n...

Comment: Why should allocating of a string of length `2m` take twice the time of allocating a string of length `m` ?

Comment: Of course it depends on how strings are instantiated in Python, I am considering allocating an array of n characters even though I don't actually know how it is done

Comment: @DisplayName: because characters need to be copied into the new string object each time. So concatenating 10 characters to another 10 characters takes order 20 steps to produce the new string. Do this in a loop, and you get quadratic behaviour.

Comment: @PadriacCunningham: note that the concatenation is **reversed** here; the character is prepended. The optimisation in that post **does not apply here**. Which is why I generally recommend against relying on that, it is too easy to misunderstand when it is applied.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, in your case<sup>*1</sup> string concatenation requires all characters to be copied, this is a O(N+M) operation (where N and M are the sizes of the input strings). M appends of the same word will trend to O(M^2) time therefor.

You can avoid this quadratic behaviour by using `str.join()`:

```
word = ''.join(list_of_words)
```

which only takes O(N) (where N is the total length of the output). Or, if you are repeating a single character, you can use:

```
word = m * char
```

You are prepending characters, but building a list first, then reversing it (or using a `collections.deque()` object to get O(1) prepending behaviour) would still be O(n) complexity, easily beating your O(N^2) choice here.

---

<sup>*1</sup> As of Python 2.4, the CPython implementation avoids creating a new string object when using `strA += strB` or `strA = strA + strB`, but this optimisation is both fragile and not portable. Since you use `strA = strB + strA` (prepending) the optimisation doesn't apply.

Comment: No, I cannot do either things.
As I said, my code above is simplified, the characters I concat are different and putting them in a list would not optimise the code in the end.

Comment: @Generalbrus: Putting them in a list would avoid the quadratic behaviour, so that *definitely* optimises the performance.

Comment: From the way I access the characters (they are in a trie), I would have to reverse the list I created before joining, so I think I'm better off operating on char arrays instead of strings in my case.
Thanks for the tips though.

Comment: @Generalbrus: use `collections.deque` and append the items to the front then.

Comment: @Generalbrus: or append and then reverse, that's still O(n). Avoiding quadratic behaviour is definitely worth it here.

Comment: How does M appends of the same word trends to M^2? 

The number of chars copied at each iteration would be: (M+M) + (2M+M) + (3M+M)+…(MM + M) = 2M + 3M + 4M + … + M^2 = M(1+2+3+…+M) = M * M(M+1)/2. 

So, shouldn’t M concatenations of the same word of length M in Python using “+” be O(M^3)?

Comment: @karahbit: I should not have used `M` for both the number of characters and the number of times you append in the loop. Only if the length of the word is equal to the number of times that you append is the complexity O(M^3), but **that's not the case here**. Keep the length of the appended text out of it, because that's a fixed amount (it's the average length of what you append), and only look at how many times you are appending.