# python 2.7 string reverse

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I need to implement string reverse by myself in Python 2.7 other than using system library, wondering if any more efficient solutions? I tried my code runs slow for a very long string (e.g. a few thousand characters). Thanks.

For string reverse I mean, for example, given s = "hello", return "olleh".

```
def reverseString(self, s):
    """
    :type s: str
    :rtype: str
    """
    if not s:
        return ''
    temp = []
    result=''
    for i in range(len(s)-1,-1,-1):
        result += s[i]
    return result
```

regards,
Lin

Comment: I understand that this is the reason why you try to avoid explicit loops in python.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would need to implement this yourself, what's your reason?

Comment: When you say slow, how slow do you mean? I'm getting reasonable performance up to 50,000 length strings (less than a quarter of a second).

Comment: Also, try using `xrange` instead of `range`

Comment: Has anybody tried with generators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT: Actually, I was mistaken

I did a rough-and-dirty test comparing the two functions and the complexity looks to be the same: linear

[image]

It seems that since Python 2.4, for CPython, there has been an optimisation avoiding the quadratic behavior. See the following answer to a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37133870/5014455

**What I said below is outdated for Python 2.7.**

This is going to be O(n^2) because strings are immutable in Python so:

```
result += s[i]
```

Will touch ever element in the resulting string *every iteration in the loop*. It will be faster to build up a mutable container (e.g. a list) of individual characters and then "".join them at the end.

```
def reverseString(s):
    """
    :type s: str
    :rtype: str
    """
    if not s:
        return ''
    result = []
    for i in xrange(len(s)-1,-1,-1):
        result.append(s[i])
    return "".join(result)
```

Comment: Thanks juanpa.arrivillaga, your solution is pretty cool, I think the issue of my code is when executing `result += s[i]`, a new string will be created other than appending to existing string, since Python str object is constant?

Comment: @LinMa The most Pythonic solution is using slice notation (`string[::-1]`) But I'm not sure what restrictions you are putting on yourself for making this function. If using `reversed` is "cheating" then maybe slice notation would be too.

Comment: Thanks for all the help juanpa.arrivillaga, mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
def reverseString(self, s):
    return s[::-1]
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, your solution is pretty cool, I think the issue of my code is when executing `result += s[i]`, a new string will be created other than appending to existing string, since Python str object is constant?

Comment: Likely? Why not completely? :)

Comment: The 'ol double colon one-liner... A timeless Python classic! [Does seem to copy the string](https://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try recursion

```
def reverse(str):
    if str == "":
        return str
    else:
        return reverse(str[1:]) + str[0]
```

Comment: This could be very slow depending on the size of the string and could end up breaking the max recursion limit given the inputs could be thousands of characters long.

Comment: @shuttle87, agree with you. :)