# How print text and data in one line

Tags: python

i have question How print text and data in one line, in this script what show me cpu usage and disck free space:

```
print 'MEM Usage:'
print(psutil.virtual_memory().percent)
print
print 'Disk Usage:' 
print(psutil.disk_usage('/').percent)
```

i wish to summarise all in one line to see it like this:

```
Mem Use : 40.1
SPU Use : 70.3
```

please your help, Thank you

Comment: `print 'MEM Usage: {}'.format(psutil.virtual_memory().percent)`

Comment: Or just `print('MEM Usage:', psutil.virtual_memory().percent)`.

Comment: Or `print('MEM Usage :', end='  ')` and next line `print(psutil.virtual_memory().percent)`

Comment: Klaus thanks friend its works for me like this 'MEM Usage:', psutil.virtual_memory().percent . as sharm ! You are my Hero !!

Answer (score 1):

```
import psutil
print 'MEM Usage:',psutil.virtual_memory().percent
print 'Disk Usage:',psutil.disk_usage('/').percent
```

Comment: There is no need to use string concatenation here at all

Comment: I edited it. What is the issue with string concatenation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37133870/4799172 and you're missing a closing `)` on each line

Comment: Sorry i not have anoth status to vote , Rahil , Klaus , thank you . All is work perfect!