# What's the complexity of `+=` for a string in Python

Tags: python, complexity-theory

Since it's immutable it should be `O(n)` however some optimisations are done under the hood (cf. other SO posts like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/70499811/11092636).

However, since it's neither `O(1)` neither `O(n)` (source, the benchmark I just did below), what is the complexity? Are there official sources?

[image]

MRE to reproduce:

```py
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def average_time_to_append(length):
    total_time = 0
    for _ in range(20000):  # Repeat 20000 times
        test_string = 'a' * length
        start_time = time.time()
        test_string += 'a'
        end_time = time.time()
        total_time += end_time - start_time
    return total_time / 20000  # Return the average time taken

lengths = list(range(10, 5*10**5))

# Measure
times = [average_time_to_append(length) for length in lengths]

# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(lengths, times, marker='o')
plt.xlabel('String Length')
plt.ylabel('Time to append (seconds)')
plt.title('Benchmark: Time to Append \'a\' to a String')
plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="--")
plt.savefig("test.png")
```

Comment: CPython contains an optimization so that, even though `str` objects are "publically" immutable, `x += "foo"` actually does mutate the underlying object.

Comment: This is entirely version-dependent; this is an operation that has had numerous revisions over time, as befits something where performance is an undocumented (at a language level) implementation artifact. Putting performance guarantees into documentation (such that it can't be changed without breaking compatibility with a prior language version) is a good way to make sure performance stagnates.

Comment: Anyhow -- good benchmarking in the Python world requires turning off garbage collection, which is very likely responsible for the spikes in your graph. (At minimum, collect a median rather than an average).

Comment: In most practical cases, what matters is the amortized complexity. You can approximate that by simply ignoring the spikes in the graph.