# Ignoring incomplete triplet in protein translation

Tags: python

I have a sequence of DNA of "atgactgccatggaggagtc". The problem told me to decompose it into triplets and translate the triplets into proteins. I have the code that do that. However at the end there are only 2 nucleotides left, so I can't make a triplet out of it. How can I tell Python to list "-" instead if a triplet doesn't have 3 nucleotides in it?

```py
DNA ="ATGACTGCCATGGAGGAGTC"
codon=[DNA[i:i+3]
for i in range(0,len(DNA),3)]
print(codon)

def translate(codon):
      
    table = {
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
        'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
        'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
        'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',                
        'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
        'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
        'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
        'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
        'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
        'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
        'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
        'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
        'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
        'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
        'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_',
        'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W',
    }
    protein =""
    for i in range(0, len(codon), 3):
            codons = codon[i:i + 3]
            protein+= table[codons]
    return protein

translate(DNA)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.get()`, which returns the value of the key if it exists in the dictionary, else it returns the second parameter to `.get()` (by default, `.get()` returns `None`, but we explicitly specify `-` here per the question's requirements):

Change

```py
protein += table[codons]
```

to

```py
protein += table.get(codons, '-')
```

and you'll get an output of:

```
MTAMEE-
```

---

Besides your immediate question, I would also suggest improving the code in two ways:

1. The dictionary doesn't need to be reassigned every time the function is called. Move it outside of the function.
2. [Repeated string concatenation is slow. Use `''.join()` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133547/time-complexity-of-string-concatenation-in-python)

With these extra changes, we get:

```py
DNA ="ATGACTGCCATGGAGGAGTC"
codon = [DNA[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(DNA), 3)]
table = # same as in original question, omitted for brevity

def translate(codon):
    protein = []
    for i in range(0, len(codon), 3):
        codons = codon[i:i + 3]
        protein.append(table.get(codons, '-'))
    return ''.join(protein)

print(translate(DNA))
```