# slow runtime for large input values

Tags: python, performance

This code is supposed to take a string of r (red), b (blue) and y (yellow) values and combine them, pairwise, to find one resulting colour. For example, 'rybbry' -> 'brbyb' -> 'yyrr' -> 'ybr' -> 'ry' -> 'b'. It works for small inputs, but forever for big ones. Too many nested loops?

```
def colour_trio(colours):
  while len(colours) > 1:
    new_colours = ''
    for i in range(len(colours) - 1):
      if colours[i:i+2] == 'rr' or colours[i:i+2] == 'by' or colours[i:i+2] == 'yb':
        new_colours = new_colours + 'r'
      elif colours[i:i+2] == 'bb' or colours[i:i+2] == 'ry' or colours[i:i+2] == 'yr':
        new_colours = new_colours + 'b'
      else:
        new_colours = new_colours + 'y'
    colours = new_colours
  
  if len(colours) == 1:
    if colours[0] == 'b':
        return 'b'
    if colours[0] == 'y':
        return 'y' 
    if colours[0] == 'r':
        return 'r'
```

Tried this as well. Still runtime is too long.

```
def colour_trio(colours):
  colours = list(colours)
  length = len(colours)
  for i in range(length-1):
    for k in range(length - 1 - i):
      colours[k] = color_sum(colours[k:k+2])
  return colours[0]

def color_sum(pair):
    if pair[0] == pair[1]:
        return pair[0]
    if 'r' in pair:
        if 'b' in pair:
            return 'y'
        return 'b'
    return 'r'
```

Here is what the tester file looks like:

```
def colour_trio_generator(seed):
    rng = random.Random(seed)
    items = ''
    for n in islice(pyramid(3, 4, 1), 10000):
        items += rng.choice('ryb')
        yield items
        if len(items) == n:
            items = rng.choice('ryb')
```

Comment: I didn't understand the rules for transforming the input to the output.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the code helps with that. For string length `n` you take `n-1` pairs and compact all of them at once. It's `O(n^2)` actually with a lot strings copied over and over, so it's not strange it works so slow. Thinking how it could be improved.

Comment: This isn't going to be a major speed-up, but an obvious improvement would be to assign `colours[i:i+2]` to a variable, rather than performing that slice six times.

Comment: Using list instead of string could be significant speed-up.

Comment: @kosciej16 in what sense should I be using a list?

Comment: @JacopoStifani see BrokenBenchamrk solution, he used that idea.

Comment: @kosciej16 Actually strings can be faster, see the benchmarks in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes use of [repeated string concatencation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37133547/17769815). Each addition operation on a string takes `O(n)` time, because strings are immutable. This operation occurs `O(n^2)` times, so the runtime of your algorithm is `O(n^3)`, where `n` is the length of the string.

One optimization is to use a list to store the letters, and then call `' '.join()`, taking the runtime from `O(n^3)` to `O(n^2)`:

```py
def colour_trio(colours):
    result = colours
    
    while len(result) != 1:
        letters = []
        for fst, snd in zip(result, result[1:]):
            if fst == snd:
                letters.append(fst)
            else:
                [letter_to_add] = list(set('ryb') - set(fst) - set(snd))
                letters.append(letter_to_add)
            
        result = ''.join(letters)
        
    return result
    
print(colour_trio("rybbry")) # Prints "b"
```

Comment: This makes sense. I ran it on my tester and the function is still too slow.

Comment: What input size are you running on?

Comment: big enough that it takes more than 20 seconds

Comment: I meant the length of the string, not the number of seconds it takes to run.

Comment: I understand... i don't know what the string length is, a tester automatically generates one long enough that the code takes over 20 seconds to execute.

Comment: Do you have any information on constraint size, where these strings come from, etc.? There's not much we can do without this information.

Comment: I've added the tester code to the OP. Not sure how to read it though.

Comment: This actually appears to be the *slowest* so far, see benchmarks in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is faster than the last solution I posted and faster than other solutions, I think classes make everything tidy looking, but you can re-work it to become a single function.

PS. Thank you for the feedback @KellyBundy! Now the algorithm is correct, it took even fewer chars!

### New Solution

```
colors = ['r', 'b', 'y']

def split(x):
    return [f'{Couple(i)}' for i in [f'{x[i]}{x[i+1]}' for i in range(len(x)-1)]]

class Couple:
    def __init__(self, x) -> None:
        self.a = x[0]
        self.b = x[1]

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        if self.a == self.b:
            return self.a
        return (set(colors).difference(set((self.a, self.b))).pop())

def ColoursTrio(x):
    while len(x) > 1:
        x = split(x)
    return x[0]

print(ColoursTrio('bbr'))
```

or even shorter (and faster):

```
def ColoursTrio(x):
    while len(x) > 1:
        x = [f'''{i[0] if i[0] == i[1] 
            else  set("rby").difference(set((i[0],
            i[1]))).pop()}''' for i in [f'{x[i]}{x[i+1]}' 
            for i in range(len(x)-1)]]
    return x[0]

print(ColoursTrio('bbr'))
```

---

### Old Solution

This is almost a bit convoluted but I think it's faster, I also think it's very similar to the one posted by @BrokenBenchmark (and I think his is better) so I'll add his example string too!

```
COLORS = ['r','b','y']

class ColorsCouple:
    def __init__(self, x:str, y:str) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def mix(self):
        if self.x == self.y:
            return f'{self.x}'
        if 'y' in (self.x, self.y):
            return set(COLORS).difference((self.x, self.y)).pop()
        return 'y'

class Colors:
    def __init__(self, colors:str) -> None:
        self.colors = self.get_couples([*colors])
    
    def get_couples(self, element):
        return [(element[i],element[i+1]) for i in range(len(element)-1)]

    def get_color(self):
        colors = [ColorsCouple(*couples).mix() if len(couples)==2 else couples[0] for couples in self.colors]
        while len(colors)>1:       
            colors = self.get_couples(colors)
            colors = [ColorsCouple(*couples).mix() if len(couples)==2 else couples[0] for couples in colors]
        return colors[0]

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.get_color()}'

print(Colors('bbr'))
print(Colors('rybbry'))
```

Comment: Yeah, Kelly, I just noticed that the algorithm is way different than I read, I wrote it at work in a coffee pause (not that it justifies me!). Mine took groups of colors, but not all groups! I'll write another one in a couple of minutes since I'll be having a coffe :)

Comment: @KellyBundy adjusted the coupling of charachters! I'm ready for your benchmark!

Comment: Ok, updated my benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, first some benchmark results, with random strings of 70 to 560 letters (I think 140 is the maximum in the actual tests):

```
 n= 70   n=140   n=280   n=560 
  0.03    0.06    0.11    0.24  Kelly_linear (I might show this one later)
  0.47    1.71    6.58   25.85  Kelly        (this is the one I am already showing)
  0.77    3.17   12.50   52.57  Jacopo_2
  1.59    6.38   25.62  107.81  Jacopo_1
  1.69    7.09   27.93  110.67  Fabio
  1.82    7.69   30.17  120.77  BrokenBenchmark
```

My solution is the function `Kelly` below. First I double every letter, then trim first and last letter. So `rybbry` becomes `ryybbbbrry`. Essentially that gives me all the pairs, if you think spaces into it then it would be `ry yb bb br ry`. Then I replace pairs of *different* letters with what that pair shall become, but in uppercase. So I get `BRbbYB`. Then replace pairs of *equal* letters with what that pair shall become: `BRBYB`. Then just go back to lower case. Repeat until done.

Full benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVZLb9s4EL7rV3BbFBIbRYji7QMG1EMOPXSBPSxyWRiCINlUzLVeIGnE2iC/PTtDUQ/KUrcCbJjz4Mx8883ITauOdbX52oi3twPLyR@sKFpvXxf1WUi6dQg8z0deMFKwapCT3yISdkp8jJhEpLcYVPgEgjVFumeem7k@cbPMpSt6gXohVvUt6tt2pt@F29swXgup7/zbpZMomRGtuegwf01d2syI1hLXLg@WizCitSjZz/VC/Dxk2y5WUdTPTHi0kwqmzqLq@@M42OEf6b5u6iS0mrzQ4m99hyv2nIwddl0tzGtBOOEVEWn1xDzL85aEtCcHz/voO77lN/cxiSLdYgIXLGgA@xUNtGBknJ3T9HQDt7vGjhXL4QH6lSBiPbz41fDZGF6yX/RpO59FvaNRtBCOhvGbFHhnipvkafrfp3Rt3C4YAwQr1mLBGsCe0ureotVYT8GlGlSggXKe1BEVk7qcJV6B2W3PJ9Se5lrkG3z4wLk@6xNkrQ8ikefSG8TbEzQVg9njAVXqSkaPJuWCDjjjySChf4bxFRrGpPcAcDBZlI6mKM8W5HYL1lo4h/1B1CdWPbBqfyxTcZptbsHkuVAGBWwEPLOV3pnMN3rBlGK6cbtxsSL6uVQ@kdUB8/@XN8bdN5FgE8fULgnKBR8EDbxs1SRQkDYNqw4emNr7zJ6hYeN3bomqk/RwiHt@SaZwFcP7BfiAB7zO/ITolP5feOta23rSEIOp6wb/1LwyTjCVU0vTp864a9X3NOO1d7l6qV4muxafC6Keu677wpFuACA3tOPAOXIFD9H1vRNZ@44GB57nTAAdmEbDQ1ffbghcQikNmrrx6CuEGWcOor5cdjx@xe@bMH517WgLS/9CYTjjeFrzBSfA6WYTGfTlzifh7/B1/xW@Pn2@c/Jztdfc0m76L0eXY79ErFPYnTR83c8Z6X0H4uWiLoniJeOK8LKphSIAegroJygVJJVaLZCrDUuVY6yglkNdOs6j1CntYl1mgmXqPGMHz2bVgNAU1vVLrTr1eCUjXp/o0l@mnkZdHsH@WPM9k/jHBV/wp6iLN@EuckmcK282aE9FnaVFzzh7qxjGYmrTZWs4dGnYHtV/1hWzhx3sfaixH3ZdGgrkLDZ6l1iDRtaD7HxSncuMiSicTR3Q2QTkUke8nu4hoYVaUikZNs2UFBljO5thnu1l8p40glfK@@i5H74Em5yUkrjkA/EU@UhCtqG6aIXVSmAGA39Jd9tNTH0NRZAkVVqyJBlu7W/sBP3tuUuq6KXr23bzSroJu2KQAWYE@lEugA20nCP@ONSHmCs5QXgs8HNwn69V9yiXKzLFvL39Bw)):

```
def Kelly(colours):
    while len(colours) != 1:
        colours = (colours
            .replace('b', 'bb')
            .replace('r', 'rr')
            .replace('y', 'yy')
            [1:-1]
            .replace('br', 'Y').replace('rb', 'Y')
            .replace('by', 'R').replace('yb', 'R')
            .replace('ry', 'B').replace('yr', 'B')
            .replace('bb', 'B')
            .replace('rr', 'R')
            .replace('yy', 'Y')
            .lower())
    return colours

def Jacopo_1(colours):
  while len(colours) > 1:
    new_colours = ''
    for i in range(len(colours) - 1):
      if colours[i:i+2] == 'rr' or colours[i:i+2] == 'by' or colours[i:i+2] == 'yb':
        new_colours = new_colours + 'r'
      elif colours[i:i+2] == 'bb' or colours[i:i+2] == 'ry' or colours[i:i+2] == 'yr':
        new_colours = new_colours + 'b'
      else:
        new_colours = new_colours + 'y'
    colours = new_colours
  if len(colours) == 1:
    if colours[0] == 'b':
        return 'b'
    if colours[0] == 'y':
        return 'y' 
    if colours[0] == 'r':
        return 'r'

def Jacopo_2(colours):
  colours = list(colours)
  length = len(colours)
  for i in range(length-1):
    for k in range(length - 1 - i):
      colours[k] = color_sum(colours[k:k+2])
  return colours[0]
def color_sum(pair):
    if pair[0] == pair[1]:
        return pair[0]
    if 'r' in pair:
        if 'b' in pair:
            return 'y'
        return 'b'
    return 'r'

def BrokenBenchmark(colours):
    result = colours    
    while len(result) != 1:
        letters = []
        for fst, snd in zip(result, result[1:]):
            if fst == snd:
                letters.append(fst)
            else:
                [letter_to_add] = list(set('ryb') - set(fst) - set(snd))
                letters.append(letter_to_add)
            
        result = ''.join(letters)        
    return result

def Fabio(x):
    while len(x) > 1:
        x = [f'''{i[0] if i[0] == i[1] 
            else  set("rby").difference(set((i[0],
            i[1]))).pop()}''' for i in [f'{x[i]}{x[i+1]}' 
            for i in range(len(x)-1)]]
    return x[0]

lengths = 70, 140, 280, 560
funcs = [
    Kelly,
    Jacopo_2,
    Jacopo_1,
    Fabio,
    BrokenBenchmark,
]

from timeit import default_timer as timer, repeat
import random

Tss = [[] for _ in funcs]
for length in lengths:
    tss = [[] for _ in funcs]
    for _ in range(5):
        colours = ''.join(random.choices('bry', k=length))
        def run():
            global result
            result = func(colours)
        expect = None
        for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
            t = min(repeat(run, number=1))
            if expect is None:
                expect = result
            assert result == expect
            ts.append(t)
           # print(*('%7.3f ms ' % (t * 1e3) for t in sorted(ts)[:3]), func.__name__)
       # print()
    print(*(f' n={length:3} ' for length in lengths))
    for func, Ts, ts in zip(funcs, Tss, tss):
        Ts.append(min(ts))
        print(*('%6.2f ' % (t * 1e3) for t in Ts), func.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: Wonderful idea! Would never have  thought of this. Works like a (py)charm. Still running just over 10s for the tester, but at least under 20.

Comment: @JacopoStifani Yeah I'm really not sure whether this is intended to be solved in quadratic or linear time. It *can* be done in linear time. See the first row of the benchmark results I just added :-)

Comment: Incredible. This is an introductory course in Python, so at this stage of my learning I am just trying to wrap my brain around the question at hand. Optimization for us means execution under 20 seconds. I'll worry about faster runtimes on my next revisit.