# Deriving pattern for runs of letters

Tags: python

I have a list of string "1. AGGCHRUSHCCKSGDSKCGGHCSG"
I would like to get all "G" in my string and print a pattern like this:
GG-G-GG-G

and if there are no Gs in my string, it should print "No G found".

I have tried basic string, substring, and print in python, but that's all I got. I can't find an Excel formula for this either. How can I generate this pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to replace sequences of one or more non-"G" characters with a single dash, and then use `.strip()` to remove any leading or trailing dashes:

```py
import re

data = "1. AGGCHRUSHCCKSGDSKCGGHCSG"
result = re.sub(r"[^G]+", r"-", data).strip("-")
if "G" in result:
    print(result)
else:
    print("No G found")
```

This outputs:

```py
GG-G-GG-G
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - With @PranavHosangadi's suggestions:

```
from itertools import groupby

string = "1. AGGCHRUSHCCKSGDSKCGGHCSG"

groups = ("".join(group) for key, group in groupby(string) if key == "G")

print("-".join(groups))
```

Output:

```
GG-G-GG-G
>>>
```

Comment: You could improve the efficiency of this code by joining letters in each group when  you calculate `groups` and also by replacing that list comprehension with a generator expression. `groups = ("".join(group) for key,  group in groupby(string) if key == "G"); "-".join(groups)`

Answer (score -1):

```
string1= "1. AGGCHRUSHCCKSGDSKCGGHCSG"
string2=""
for char in string1:
    if char=='G':
        string2+=char
    else:
        string2+='-'
print(string2)
```

like this?

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output, and [repeated string concatenation is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37133547/17769815).