# How to create a brute-force password cracker for alphabetical and alphanumerical passwords?

Tags: python, python-3.x, brute-force, cracking

I'm trying to create a brute force Python code for alphabetical and alphanumerical combinations and have it report the password and amount of time it took.

For numerical combinations I made this:

```
import datetime as dt

Password4 = 123456

def crack_password():
    start = dt.datetime.now()
    for n in range(1000000):
        password_guess = '{0:04d}'.format(n)
             if password_guess == str(Password4):
                end = dt.datetime.now()
                print("Password found: {} in {}".format(password_guess, end - start))
               break
    guesses = crack_password()
```

For alphanumerical combinations (does not work) I tried:

```
import random

letters = [str(i) for i in range('a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p')]
s = [''.join([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]) for a in letters for b in letters for c   in letters for d in letters for e in letters for f in letters for g in letters  for h in letters]
random.shuffle(s)
real_password = 'aaaaaaaa'
i = 0

for code in s:
if code == real_password:
    print()
        print('The password is: ', code)
        break
    else:
        i += 1
        print(i, ' failures', end='\r')
```

It should report either number of attempts or time it took.

Comment: `letters = [str(i) for i in range('a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p')]` doesn't work as you think....

Comment: `letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyz'` is what you're aiming for

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a naiive brute force method that will guess numbers (`string.digits`) and lower case letters (`string.ascii_lowercase`). You can use `itertools.product` with `repeat` set to the current password length guessed. You can start at `1` character passwords (or whatever your lower bound is) then cap it at a maximum length too. Then just `return` when you find the match.

```
import itertools
import string

def guess_password(real):
    chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    attempts = 0
    for password_length in range(1, 9):
        for guess in itertools.product(chars, repeat=password_length):
            attempts += 1
            guess = ''.join(guess)
            if guess == real:
                return 'password is {}. found in {} guesses.'.format(guess, attempts)
            # uncomment to display attempts, though will be slower
            #print(guess, attempts)

print(guess_password('abc'))
```

Output

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
...
aba 1369
abb 1370
password is abc. found in 1371 guesses.
```

Comment: @AlexH One can use `print(guess, attempts,end="\r")` to rewrite the same line, but why does it even matters to print the failed password avoid it and save some cpu cycles.

Answer (score 2):

One possible option which would preserve almost exactly your current code is to convert to base 36 with the following "digits": `0-9a-z`. This will give you every possible alpha-numeric combination for n characters if you search in `range(36**n)`.

Using a simplified function from [How to convert an integer in any base to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/convert-integer-to-a-string-in-a-given-numeric-base-in-python):

```
def baseN(num, b=36, numerals="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
    return ((num == 0) and numerals[0]) or (baseN(num // b, b, numerals).lstrip(numerals[0]) + numerals[num % b])
```

You can then loop through numbers as in your example:

```
>>> for i in range(10000, 10005):
...     print(baseN(i).zfill(5))
...
007ps
007pt
007pu
007pv
007pw
```

To get all 3-letter possibilities, you can loop as follows:

```
for i in range(36**3):
    possible = baseN(i).zfill(3)
```

Comment: I like this solution as it shows more explicitely how the counting with a different base works. One remark: your use of zfills assumes that the first character in the numerals is a zero character. To make it more generic, it is better to do baseN(i).rjust(3, numerals[0])