# Converting to and from base91

Tags: python, string, encoding, base91

I know that base91, [as defined by Joachim Henke](http://base91.sourceforge.net/), uses these characters:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~"
```

What steps should one perform in order to convert strings to and from base91?

Comment: I am doing this in Python

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Nothing really much as I don't know the pattern. I read this : http://base91.sourceforge.net/

Comment: There's a Python package popping up when I google for it.

Comment: There is a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/how-to-convert-an-integer-in-any-base-to-a-string

Comment: the pattern is explained [here](https://www.dcode.fr/base-91-encoding). You can also read the source code at the [homepage](http://base91.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base91, how is it calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978133/base91-how-is-it-calculated)