# Decode arbitrary base encoded value to string

Tags: python, radix

Trying to decode what appears to be base encoded. (24 characters total, ends with padding '=='. I would post it but I am not sure what it contains...) I expect a human readable value and I've tried guessing at the encoding type/base.

One solution could be to iterate over possible base encoding values and then eyeball them. But that would also require dynamically determining the corresponding alphabet library for each base encoding... [How to convert an integer in any base to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/how-to-convert-an-integer-in-any-base-to-a-string)

How can the base encoding be determined for an arbitrary base encoded value?

Comment: Can we assume you've tried to decide it as Base64? How about the closely-related ancient uuencode? How many different letters are in the data?

Comment: Yes, tried base64. Contains upper and lower case alpha numeric. Only symbol is a forward slash at pos 18. This seems to indicate a base64 encoding, but the decoded value makes no sense given the context where the value was found. Format: (4aaAaaaaAaAA2AAAA/AaaA==)

Comment: This value was recovered from an LDAP database.

Comment: If the value was human-readable it wouldn't need to be encoded.

Comment: I'm not aware of any encoding scheme other than Base64 that's likely to end in `==`.  You said you tried Base64, what were the results?  If the original data was truly human-readable, there wouldn't have been much need in encoding it.

Comment: Based on the other attributes surrounding the LDAP field where this was found, I'm expecting human readable. Sorry, I would post the base64 decoding, but I am still working out if that could possibly be a hash of some kind. The result of the base64 decode is a 32 digit upper/lower alpha numberic with no special chars.

Comment: What's the smallest/largest byte in the base64-decoded value? And does the LDAP field have a name?

Comment: Sorry @StefanPochmann, how would I determine that?

Comment: This seems more like a puzzle (you guess at what to do) than a programming problem. Not sure if SO is the correct site for this. Anyway... just post the content and people will take a look.

Comment: @primohacker Like `max(b64decode('4aaAaaaaAaAA2AAAA/AaaA=='))`.

Comment: min/max of base64 decoded value: Min = 0 (zero) and max = x (lowercase)

Comment: That doesn't look like the actual bytes but like of a hex representation. Anyway... base64-encoded md5 sums of passwords seems to be a thing in LDAP and it has the right length. Try https://security.stackexchange.com/q/12795

Comment: @StefanPochmann, based on what I'm now seeing I think you are right. This does appear to be base64 encoded md5 hash.