# converitng ASCII values of a string to base 3 number representation in Python

Tags: python

I am having troubles executing the code that converts each character in the string to its base 3 number representation.

This code works for printing the decimal and binary number representations:

```
print(["{0} {0:06b} ".format(ord(c)-ord('a')) for c in PT])
```

Where the user inputs values for PT.

I have tried using this code :

```
print(["{0} {0:04b} ".format(ord(c)-ord('a')) for c in PT])
```

but this does not output base 3.

Any help on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you expect it to output base 3? `b` is for binary. There's no format operator for base 3, you need to write your own function for that.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2267446/5014455) is a recipe for converting to any base, by Alex Martelli himself

Comment: or use the `gmpy2` library

Comment: @Barmar I realized that `ord(c)` was creating an integer out of every character in the string. Thanks for finding the dupe.