# Converting bases using int()

Tags: python

I am a little confused with how int() works when converting a number from base 10 to base 3 in Python.

This code will print out the converted base 3 numbers from the range given by the user.

```
Value=0
Number=int(input("Please Input A Number "))    
for i in range(0,Number):
    Value=int(i,base=3)
    print(Value)
```

I have TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base returned as an error.

An example of what I am trying to achieve.
Example 32 in base 3 is 1012
Perhaps I am confused to what int(x,base=y) actually does to the number.

Comment: You are converting the other way around.  `int(i, 3)` converts a string representation of a base 3 number to base 10.  For example, `int('e5e2', 16)` returns `58850`, which is the base 10 representation of `e5e2`

Comment: So this code will not convert the integer into another integer? Example 32 in base 3 is 1012

Comment: @BubblesPop No, it will not. The error message is very explicit about it as well as the docstring.

Comment: "Example 32 in base 3 is 1012" The thing that needs to be understood here is that **integers do not have a base**. The **string representation of** an integer can **represent it in** a base. That much isn't a programming question; it's a math/general terminology question. Numbers are conceptually distinct from how they are represented, much like how it is impossible to write the word "house" on a piece of paper and then live in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert a number from Base 10 to Base 3, which is not what `int()` does.  From the documentation:

> class int(x, base=10)
>
> Return an integer object constructed from a number or string x, or
>   return 0 if no arguments are given.

It does not convert to other bases, it converts from the specified base to an integer.

If you want to convert a number from Base 10 to Base 3, you can use the following, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2267428/3483203).  I slightly adapted it for readability, so it only converts to Base 3.

```
def baseThree(num, numerals="012"):
    return ((num == 0) and numerals[0]) or (baseThree(num // 3, numerals).lstrip(numerals[0]) + numerals[num % 3])

print(baseThree(32))
```

Output:

```
1012
```

Adapted for your specific question:

```
num = int(input("Please Input A Number "))
for i in range(0, num):
     print(baseThree(i))
```

Output with `num = 5`:

```
Please Input A Number 5
0
1
2
10
11
```

Comment: Thanks! When I saw that int() had a base parameter, i thought that it would simply convert the number. Can I ask where you would use int() with the base parameter?

Comment: You can use it to convert strings representations of numbers in  other bases to base 10.  For example, `int('101', 2)` returns `5`

Answer (score 0):

The internal representation of numbers is base-less. You can only convert strings with a given base to numbers:

```
>>> int("21", 3)
7
>>> bin(int("21", 3))
'0b111'
>>> hex(int("21", 3))
'0x7'
```

Comment: This is correct, but I think he is confused about which way the conversion is going in this case.  It seems like he wants to convert from base 10 to base 3.

Comment: So this code will not convert the integer into another integer? Example 32 in base 3 is 1012

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue comes from the data type of i. According to the documentation in Python 2.7 and 3.6, the value you wish to convert must be a string when a base is provided.

> "If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string, bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in radix base."

Therefore, in order for your code to work, you must convert the value of i to a string.

```
int((str(i)), 3)
```