# Your browser tried to send a message without supplying a form boundary in the post

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, request, python-requests

Trying to submit a post request to a really old website.

I am trying to post a payload similar to this (this is from google)

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryosJxc86zagk885w4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hashid"

+13334445555
------WebKitFormBoundaryosJxc86zagk885w4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="reqUID"

ajpm
------WebKitFormBoundaryosJxc86zagk885w4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recipients"


------WebKitFormBoundaryosJxc86zagk885w4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file-name"


------WebKitFormBoundaryosJxc86zagk885w4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

too%20complicated
------WebKitFormBoundaryosJxc86zagk885w4--
```

with these headers (from inspect element):

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:547
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryosJxc86zagk885w4
Host:127.0.0.1:333
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:333
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:333/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

to `http://127.0.0.1:333/sendMessage.srv`.

I am using this simple python script to do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import requests
url = "http://127.0.0.1:333/sendMessage.srv/"
message = "hello"
number = "+13334445555"
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/how-to-convert-an-integer-in-any-base-to-a-string
def baseN(num,b,numerals="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
    return ((num == 0) and numerals[0]) or (baseN(num // b, b, numerals).lstrip(numerals[0]) + numerals[num % b]) 
reqId = baseN(round(random.random() * 1679616), 36) 
data = { 
        'hashid':number,
        'reqUID':reqId,
        'recipients':"",
        'file-name':"",
        'text':message,
}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
print(r.text)
print("finished")
```

It gives me a `200 OK` but it says `Your browser tried to send a message without supplying a form boundary in the post.`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your header is missing in the request. you have to provide the `Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryosJxc86zagk885w4` otherwise it will be `text/plain` by default.

Comment: I can't get it to work `headers={"content-type":"multipart/form-data"}`

Comment: Your server is messed up it it answers with 200 OK as Response Code then throws an error message in the body. PS: your ContentType should contain the boundary string too, I assume.

Comment: trying `headers={"content-type":"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryosJxc86zagk885w4"})` and printing `r.headers.get("content-type")` gives me `text/plain`?!?