# Combining numbers together to form multiple digit number

Tags: python, math, python-3.7

I'm trying to combine multiple numbers together in python 3.7 but I'm having no luck.

I want it to be like such:

```
1 + 4 + 5 = 145
```

I know this is simple but I'm getting nowhere!

Comment: `int(str(1)+ str(4) + str(5))`

Comment: If you know the numbers are all one digit: `100*x + 10*y + z`.  Otherwise, `int(str(x) + str(y) + str(z))`.

Comment: If you want to do this numerically rather than… stringeriffically (there must be a word for that…), you need to think about how base-10 numbers work: `digit * 10**i`, where `i` ranges from `n-1` to `0`.

Comment: @abarnert: It's usually just called "string processing" or "string manipulation". [`Snobol`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNOBOL) is/was really good at it.

Comment: @martineau Sure, but what's the adverb? "String processing-wise"? That just sounds terrible.

Comment: @abarnert: Textually then — and it's a relatively short adverb.

Comment: @martineau Ah, yeah, that works. Thanks for fixing my aphasia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just write a function that concatenates numbers or any other object/datatype as a string

```
concatenate = lambda *args : ''.join([str(arg) for arg in args])

a = 1

print(concatenate(4, 5, 6))

print(concatenate(a, MagicNumber(1), "3"))
```

But also in python you can make a class and write magic functions that control the way that objects of your class are added, subtracted etc. You could make a class to store a number and add it like you want to. You could save this code in a file and import it or paste it into your own script.

```
class MagicNumber():
    value = 0

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = int(value)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.value

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value

    def __add__(self, b):
        return MagicNumber(str(self)+str(b))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = MagicNumber(4)
    b = MagicNumber(5)
    c = MagicNumber(6)

    print(a+b+c)

    #You could even do this but I strongly advise against it
    print(a+5+6)
```

And heres a link to the documentation about these "magic methods"
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: Approach is overkill IMO.

Comment: I made the second solution more simplified. Thanks for the feedback @martineau

Comment: West: I meant wrt creating a custom `class` to do this. Python has tons of built-in text processing features which, if used properly, would likely result in less code being needed and would also run significantly faster.

Comment: This is the best way I can think of to make a line execute as similar as possible to the way the question's author wants it to. Also if the question's author wants to do similar things with subtract or other operators this would be a solution that covers that as well. @martineau

Comment: @West What's the string-concatenation equivalent of subtraction? I can imagine that `1 + 3 + 5 - 5` would be `13`, but should `1 + 3 + 5 - 3` be `15` or 135` or an error, and what about `1 + 3 + 5 - 2`? Multiplication might be a better example—`3 * 5` giving you `33333` is pretty unambiguous, even if it's hard to imagine when you'd want it.

Comment: I'm not sure ¯\_(ツ)_/¯, it was just an example. I like the multiplication example. It seems like the only operators that are reasonable are those that can already be used on strings. @abarnert

Comment: West & @abarnert: Who said anything about multiplication? The OP certainly didn't. West: Anyway, [Sunitha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51599607/355230) is an example of what I meant about using Python's (generally relatively very fast) built-in abilities.

Comment: @martineau West brought up "if the question's author wants to do similar things with subtract"; I was just saying that multiplication might be a better example of that, because string multiplication is a defined operation, unlike subtraction. I don't see any problem with him suggesting, especially in a comment, how his solution could be extended in ways that other solutions can't.

Comment: @abarnert: Like I said originally, overkill, not to mention pure speculation and likely way over the head of the OP.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce` to do this in a mathematical way

```
>>> l = [1, 4, 5]
>>> 
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: 10*x+y, l)
145
```

Alternatively, you can use string concat

```
>>> int(''.join(map(str, l)))
145
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this numerically, consider what base-10 numerals means:

```
145 = 1 * 10**2 + 4 * 10**1 + 5 * 10**0
```

So, you need to get N numbers that range from N-1 to 0, in lockstep with the digits. One way to do this is with `enumerate` plus a bit of extra arithmetic:

```
def add_digits(*digits):
    total = 0
    for i, digit in enumerate(digits):
        total += digit * 10**(len(digits)-i-1)
    return total
```

Now:

```
>>> add_digits(1, 4, 5)
145
```

Of course this only works with sequences of digits—where you know how many digits you have in advance. What if you wanted to work with any iterable of digits, even an iterator coming for a generator expression or something? Then you can rethink the problem:

```
1456 = ((1 * 10 + 4) * 10 + 5) * 10 + 6
```

So:

```
def add_digits(digits):
    total = 0
    for digit in digits:
        total = total * 10 + digit
    return total

>>> add_digits((1, 3, 5, 6))
1356
>>> add_digits(n for n in range(10) if n%2)
13579
```

---

Notice that you can easily extend either version to other bases:

```
def add_digits(*digits, base=10):
    total = 0
    for i, digit in enumerate(digits):
        total += digit * base**(len(digits)-i-1)
    return total

>>> hex(add_digits(1, 0xF, 2, 0xA, base=16))
'0x1f2a'
```

… which isn't *quite* as easy to do with the stringy version; you can't just do `int(''.join(map(str, digits)), base)`, but instead need to replace that `str` with a function that converts to a string in a given base. Which there are [plenty of solutions for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/), but no obvious and readable one-liner.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You should try casting the numbers as strings! When you do something like this

```
str(1)+str(4)+str(5)
```

You will get 145, but it will be a string. If you want it to be a number afterwards, then you can cast the whole thing as an integer.

```
int(str(1)+str(4)+str(5))
```

or just set the answer to a new variable and cast that as an integer.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to concat them as strings, and then parse it back into a number.

```
x = str(1) + str(4) + str(5)
print(int(x))
```

or

```
int(str(1) + str(4) + str(5))
```