# Python: Replace Numeric Value With String

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm trying to replace a value entered by a user with a string to make the output cleaner

I thought an if statement would help, but I'm not sure how it would tie in with my intended output

```
 def main() :
    number = int(input("Enter your number: "))
    base = int(input("Convert to\n" \
    "   Binary[2] - Octal[8] - Hexadecimal[16]: "))

    if base == 2 :
        "binary"
     elif base == 8 :
        "octal"
    else:
        "hexadecimal"

    print("\n"+str(number) +" in "+ str(base) + " is: " + str(convert(number, 10, base)))


  def convert(fromNum, fromBase, toBase) :
    toNum = 0
    power = 0

    while fromNum > 0 :
        toNum += fromBase ** power * (fromNum % toBase)
        fromNum //= toBase
        power += 1
    return toNum

main()
```

What I'm trying to get:
if user enters 5 as their number and 2 as conversion. Output would be:
"5 in binary is: 101"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an integer in any base to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/how-to-convert-an-integer-in-any-base-to-a-string)

Comment: Dante, could you please explain what you expect `"binary"` statement would do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 def main() :
    number = int(input("Enter your number: "))
    base = int(input("Convert to\n" \
    "   Binary[2] - Octal[8] - Hexadecimal[16]: "))
    base_string = "None"        

    if base == 2 :
        base_string = "binary"
     elif base == 8 :
        base_string = "octal"
    else:
        base_string = "hexadecimal"

    print("\n {} in {} is: {}".format(str(number), base_string, str(convert(number, 10, base))))


  def convert(fromNum, fromBase, toBase) :
    toNum = 0
    power = 0

    while fromNum > 0 :
        toNum += fromBase ** power * (fromNum % toBase)
        fromNum //= toBase
        power += 1
    return toNum

main()
```

Your issue was the "binary" part in the if-statement. It has virtually no effect neither on your code nor on your output. You have to store the literal representation ("binary",...) in some variable ("base_string"). Then you can use this variable  in your output.

Comment: Oh,I see. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, it looks like your base conversion won't actually do what you want. You should look at [How to convert an integer in any base to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/how-to-convert-an-integer-in-any-base-to-a-string) to do the conversion properly (hexadecimal has letters A-F in it, those aren't handled by your code, for example).

To accept a name instead of a number, you need to change this line of code:

```
base = int(input("Convert to\n   Binary[2] - Octal[8] - Hexadecimal[16]: "))
```

What's happening here? `input()` takes a line from stdin. In the interactive case, this means the user types something (hopefully a number) and then hits enter. We get that string. Then `int` converts that string to a number.

Your `convert` expects `base` to be a number. You want inputs like `"binary"` to correspond to `base = 2`. One way to achieve this is with a dict. It can map strings to numbers:

```
base_name_to_base = {'binary': 2, 'octal': 8, 'hexadecimal': 16}
base = base_name_to_base[input('Choose a base (binary, octal, hexadecimal): ')]
```

Note that `base_name_to_base[x]` can fail (`raise KeyError`) if `x` is not a key in the dict. So you want to handle this (what if the user enters `"blah"`?):

```
while True:
    try:
        base = base_name_to_base[input('Choose a base (binary, octal, hexadecimal): ')]
        break
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

This will loop until we hit the break (which only happens when indexing into `base_name_to_base` doesn't raise the key error.

Additionally, you may want to handle different cases (ex. `"BINARY"`) or arbitrary whitespace (ex. `"  binary  "`). You can do this by calling `.lower()` and `.strip()` on the string returned by `input()`.

Comment: It's not complete yet, I was checking to see if I got the output i wantesbefore I moved  on to the other ones, Thank you, I'll implement what you say