# Is there a quick Python function for turning numbers into different bases?

Tags: python, palindrome, radix

I'm writing a code to check how many times a number is a palindrome in bases 2-10. Is there a python function for converting numbers into different bases?

I have already tried manually creating a function, but it is too slow.

```py
baseChars="0123456789"
def toBase(n, b): 
    return "0" if not n else toBase(n//b, b).lstrip("0") + baseChars[n%b]
```

I expect the toBase function to return the number expressed in all bases from 2-10. I would like to avoid NumPy

Comment: As far as I know, no. Aside from `str` (base 10), there are separate `bin`, `oct`, and `hex` functions for producing base 2, 8, and 16 representations, respectively. `format` also only has options for bases 2, 8, and 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any single function that does this in the standard library. But working on [a different project](https://github.com/Superbird11/As-the-Numbers-Say/blob/master/heuristics.py) for one of my own classes, I had to tackle this type of problem, and my solution looked like this:

```
def _base(decimal, base):
    """
    Converts a number to the given base, returning a string.
    Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26188870/2648811
    :param decimal: an integer
    :param base: The base to which to convert that integer
    :return: A string containing the base-base representation of the given number
    """
    li = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    other_base = ""
    while decimal != 0:
        other_base = li[decimal % base] + other_base
        decimal = decimal // base
    if other_base == "":
        other_base = "0"
    return other_base

def palindromes(num, bases=range(2, 11)):
    """
    Checks if the given number is a palindrome in every given base, in order. 
    Returns the sublist of bases for which the given number is a palindrome, 
    or an empty list if it is not a palindrome in any base checked.
    :param num: an integer to be converted to various bases
    :param bases: an iterable containing ints representing bases
    """
    return [i for i in bases if _base(num, i) == _base(num, i)[::-1]]
```

(A less succinct version of that last statement (expanding the `for` loop) looks like this):

```
r = []
for i in bases:
    b = _base(num, i)
    if b == b[::-1]:
        r.append(i)
return r
```

---

In your case, if you just want a list of representations of your integer in various bases, the code would be even simpler:

```
reps = {b: _base(num, b) for base in range(2, 11)}
```

will produce a dict of `base : representation in that base`. For example, if `num = 23`:

```
{2: '10111',
 3: '212',
 4: '113',
 5: '43',
 6: '35',
 7: '32',
 8: '27',
 9: '25',
 10: '23'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is available in NumPy through [`base_repr()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.base_repr.html):

```
import numpy as np
[np.base_repr(100, base) for base in range(2,11)]
```

Result:

```
['1100100', '10201', '1210', '400', '244', '202', '144', '121', '100']
```

Comment: Hi Tom, I cannot use NumPy, because NumPy is a pip install, which I am not allowed to use. Is there another way?

Comment: You could look at the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/numeric.py#L1971) and see how they do it, it's pretty straight-forward and uses primitive operations like your current solution.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this

```
def rebase( value, new_base ):
    res = ""
    while value > 0:
      res = str( value % new_base ) + res
      value = int( value / new_base )
    return res
```