# How to encode/decode a Uint8Array in Base36 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, encoding, base36

I want to encode and decode Bytes from an Uint8Array (or an ArrayBuffer) to/from a string in Base36. JavaScript has the [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) and [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) functions which both support base36 but I am not sure if first converting 8 Bytes to a 64 bit floating point is the right idea.

In JS one can encode a BigInt (a number of arbitrary length) in Base36. However the other direction does [not work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a float to base36 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205931/how-do-i-convert-a-float-to-base36-in-python)

Comment: @DhanaD Encoding a single float in Base36 is easy in javascript. My question is if i first should convert my Byte Array to an Array of floats and then convert every float to Base36. I don't think I will be able to decode the string because the results are of different length.

Comment: @DhanaD. Please refrain from attempting to close questions as duplicates of questions in another language. See [this meta question for the discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367501/215552).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution with the help of these two posts: [Why JavaScript base-36 conversion appears to be ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63200494/why-javascript-base-36-conversion-appears-to-be-ambiguous) and [How to go between JS BigInts and TypedArrays](https://coolaj86.com/articles/convert-js-bigints-to-typedarrays/)

```js
function bigIntToBase36(num){
    return num.toString(36);
}

function base36ToBigInt(str){
    return [...str].reduce((acc,curr) => BigInt(parseInt(curr, 36)) + BigInt(36) * acc, 0n);
}

function bigIntToBuffer(bn) {
    let hex = BigInt(bn).toString(16);
    if (hex.length % 2) { hex = '0' + hex; }

    const len = hex.length / 2;
    const u8 = new Uint8Array(len);

    let i = 0;
    let j = 0;
    while (i < len) {
        u8[i] = parseInt(hex.slice(j, j+2), 16);
        i += 1;
        j += 2;
    }

    return u8;
}

function bufferToBigInt(buf) {
    const hex = [];
    const u8 = Uint8Array.from(buf);

    u8.forEach(function (i) {
        var h = i.toString(16);
        if (h.length % 2) { h = '0' + h; }
        hex.push(h);
    });

    return BigInt('0x' + hex.join(''));
}

const t1 = new Uint8Array([123, 51, 234, 234, 24, 124, 2, 125, 34, 255]);
console.log(t1);
const t2 = bigIntToBase36(bufferToBigInt(t1));
console.log(t2);
console.log(t2.length)
const t3 = bigIntToBuffer(base36ToBigInt(t2));
console.log(t3);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a package that does this very well: [multiformats](https://github.com/multiformats/js-multiformats):

```
npm install multiformats
```

And:

```
import { base36 } from "multiformats/bases/base36"

// you have to prepend your base36 string with "k":
const decoded = base36.decode("k" + "welcomebacklongtimenotseen")
console.log(decoded)

// don't forget to remove the leading "k":
const reEncoded = base36.encode(decoded).slice(1)
console.log(reEncoded)
```

This will give you the following output:

```
Uint8Array(17) [
   76, 249,  40, 198, 158, 140,
  198,  47,  99, 101, 143,  20,
   54,  15, 186, 196, 239
]
welcomebacklongtimenotseen
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative implementation of the `bufferToBigInt` method compared to the accepted answer would be:

```js
function bufferToBigInt_2(buf) {
  let ret = 0n
  for (const i of buf.values()) {
    const bi = BigInt(i)
    ret = (ret << 8n) + bi
  }
  return ret;
}
```

If you want the resulting base36 string to have a fixed length, then you can use this `bigIntToBase36` alternative:

```js
function bigIntToBase36_2(num, exactLength){
  return num.toString(36).substring(0, exactLength).padStart(exactLength, '0');
}
```