# How to implement ruby int(16).to_s(32) in python

Tags: python, ruby, encode, sha1

I have the following code in ruby:

```
hex = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(str).to_i(16)
hex.to_s(32)
```

And I tried to implement it in python:

```
import hashlib
import base64

base64.b32encode(hashlib.sha1(str).digest())
```

When I run the code for the string `test` in ruby I get `l558vpecm6dqc72c11pt74f9guc2veuj`
While in python I get `VFFI7ZOMWGN2MHCMBBZ5HEPJQ6MC7O6T`
What is wrong with the python code? How to get the same results as for ruby?

Comment: What are the conversions supposed to do? Also, did you check that the string results from the digest operation match, in the first place?

Comment: I don't know Python, but to get the Python result in Ruby, you can use the [base32](https://github.com/stesla/base32) gem: `Base32.encode(Digest::SHA1.digest('test'))`. Maybe that helps to find your problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel We already have the ruby implementation - we use the results as identifier. Now I need to implement it in new service with python. And yes I did check the digest itself match.

Comment: One version uses `digest`; the other uses `hexdigest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [gmpy](https://github.com/aleaxit/gmpy):

```
import hashlib
import gmpy2

str = 'test'
h = hashlib.sha1(str).hexdigest()
i = int(h, 16)
gmpy2.digits(i, 32)
=> 'l558vpecm6dqc72c11pt74f9guc2veuj'
```

If you don't want to use gmpy and need a native Python version of `digits`, then you can find several implementations among the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-a-string-in-any-base).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help you you will find Hashing examples in different languages: ruby, python, Go,...: https://gist.github.com/jasny/2200f68f8109b22e61863466374a5c1d