# Need help converting number and a base to binary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

so i wrote this code to take a base that is inputted by the user and a number inputted by the user and it is supposed to print the num with that base to binary. It does do what its supposed to do but it asks me for the base 3 times and then gives me the correct number here's the code

Comment: the format of the code didnt post correctly

Comment: can you paste the code you have used and probably a sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe this is a duplicate of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-a-string-in-any-base/28666223#28666223) if so then the code from their answer will work, you just need to use a base 2 to their function:

```py
def numberToBase(number, base):
    if number == 0:
        return [0]
    digits = []
    while number:
        digits.append(int(number % base))
        number //= base
    return digits[::-1]
```

So in your case:

```py
print(numberToBase(int(input("What is your number?:")), 2))
```

Or if you want a string representation I would recommend this:

```py
def number_to_base(number, base):
    if number == 0:
        return [0]
    digits = []
    while number:
        digits.append(str(number % base))
        number //= base
    return "".join(digits[::-1])
```

Comment: yeah but i want to be able to input a custom base for instance number: 42 base : 10 = 42

Comment: @JC102 the function will allow that, the b value is for base. I will update the code with better variable naming.

Comment: if i want the base to be inputted by the user do i just add a input statement where the 2 is in the code you provided

Comment: @JC102 yes, it would become ```numberToBase(int(input("What is your number?:")), int(input("What is your base?:")))```

Comment: thanks that worked would there be a way i could take out the comma and the brackets and just make it the numbers

Comment: @JC102 see the last example, also if this works please hit the checkmark so others see this answer is correct. Thanks!