# Convert column offset to column name

Tags: python, excel

Excel files can contain up to 16,384 (2<sup>14</sup>) columns. The first 26 columns are labeled "A", "B", "C", and so on. After that it is "AA", "AB", "AC", ..., "BA", "BB", "BC", ..., and so on, but two-letter labels only support an additional 26<sup>2</sup>=676 columns. So eventually we see "AAA", "AAB", "AAC", and so on, to a max of "XFD".

I'd like to write a Python function that converts a column offset/index to a column label.

| Offset | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | B |
| ... | ... |
| 25 | Z |
| 26 | AA |
| 27 | AB |
| ... | ... |
| 700 | ZY |
| 701 | ZZ |
| 702 | AAA |
| 703 | AAB |
| ... | ... |
| 16383 | XFD |

For the first 26 columns this is trivial.

```py
>>> offset = 0
>>> chr(offset + 65)
'A'
```

But how do I generalize this to support all valid inputs and outputs?

I tried adapting [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28666223/459780) and converting the offsets to numbers in base 26, and then using `chr` to convert each place value to a letter. But I couldn't get it to work as intended.

```py
def numberToBase(n, b):
    if n == 0:
        return [0]
    digits = []
    while n:
        digits.append(int(n % b))
        n //= b
    return digits[::-1]
```

Comment: Re your linked base conversion answer,  that won't work because Excel column names are not strictly base 26  [Here's a C# answer you might be able to translate to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/182924/445425)

Comment: Looks like it has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/182009/14159796

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my version using recursion:

```
def column_offset_to_column_name(index):
    if index < 0:
        return ""
    quotient, remainder = divmod(index, 26)
    return column_offset_to_column_name(quotient - 1) + chr(remainder + 65)
```