# How to multiply two real numbers of any base in Python?

Tags: python, math, multiplication

I would like to write a function that accepts two numbers and their base (aka radix) and multiplies them.

```
base = int(input())
num1 = input()
num2 = input()

def multiply(num1: str, num2: str, base: int) -> str:
    pass
```

I tried to convert them to decimal and then multiply them but the precision can be lost.

For example:

```
2
101.1
101.1
```

is

```
11110.01
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_error_mitigation

Comment: Generally, you can convert numbers to `float` without loosing precision if the base is a power of 2 (unless it doesn't fit into float on your machine). For other cases, you need a different solution.

Comment: You could jest remove the `.` and threat the number as an integer, and after the calculation add the dot back to the resulting string at the right place (position of first dot + position of second dot, counting from the right).

Comment: Consider using [decimal — Decimal fixed point and floating point arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

Comment: @AlanSTACK I don't see there anything about it being able to handle bases other than 10.

Comment: I had assumed the author was only concerned about base 10 - since his post mentions "decimal" specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code saves positions of the `.`s (if they are present) and removes them.
Strings are then converted to `int`s, multiplied and the result is converted back to string at which point a `.` is inserted at the appropriate position if necessary.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

base = 2
num1 = '101.1'
num2 = '101.1'

def parsenum(num: str, base: int) -> (int, int):
    shift = len(num) - num.index('.') - 1 if '.' in num else 0
    num = num.replace('.', '')
    return int(num, base), shift

BS="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
def to_base(s, b):
    res = ""
    while s:
        res+=BS[s%b]
        s//= b
    return res[::-1] or "0"

def num2str(num: int, shift: int, base: int) -> str:
    string = to_base(abs(num), base)
    if shift:
        if len(string) <= shift:
            string = '0' * (shift - len(string) + 1) + string
        pos = len(string) - shift
        string = string[:pos] + '.' + string[pos:]
        string = string.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
    if num < 0:
        string = '-' + string
    return string

def multiply(num1: str, num2: str, base: int) -> str:
    num1, shift1 = parsenum(num1, base)
    num2, shift2 = parsenum(num2, base)
    result_num, result_shift = num1 * num2, shift1 + shift2
    return num2str(result_num, result_shift, base)

print(multiply(num1, num2, base))
```

I'm 95% sure I've got all the corner cases, including handling negative numbers, stripping unnecessary `0`s and removing trailing `.`.

The function `to_base` is from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53675480/3052438

Answer (score 1):

```
base = 2
s1, s2 = '101.1', '101.1'

d1 = ('.' in s1 and len(s1) - s1.index('.') - 1) or 0
d2 = ('.' in s2 and len(s2) - s2.index('.') - 1) or 0
a, b = int(s1.replace('.', ''), base), int(s2.replace('.', ''), base)
scale = base**(d1+d2)
intpart, fracpart = (a*b) // scale, (a*b) % scale
res = '%s.%s' % (baseN(intpart, base), baseN(fracpart, base).rjust(d1+d2, '0'))

res # '11110.01'
```

Probably some edge cases with the formatting left to do.
The principle is 101.1 * 101.1 = (1011 * 2^-1) * (1011 * 2^-1) = 1011*1011 * 2^(-1 + -1) = 1111001 * 2^-2 = 11110.01