# Can Python be mistaken while adding large integers?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that implements an algorithm to calculate certain coefficients of some curves (low dimension topology, but that is not the point). During the calculations, sometimes is needed to add up large numbers (the larger, the better, since it would be a good idea to use this program to experiment with values as large as possible).

Can it happen that Python is mistaken while adding two relatively large (say of order $10^{500}$) integers? Is there a limit on the size of numbers, after which Python just "guesses", i.e. doesn't cause an error, yet generates an incorrect answer?

While testing, I got an error for numbers larger than $10^{4300}$, but I was wondering whether something suspicious happens for lower values.

Would you suggest using another language that better handles numbers (I am aware about the slowness of Python, but handling numbers is more important now)?

Comment: Please supply a [mcve] which consists of two large integers whose sum is computed incorrectly.

Comment: [_"Integers have unlimited precision."_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex)

Comment: Integer math will be applied correctly under all circumstances, the size does not matter.  But if at any point you convert those integers to floats, there will be inaccuracy.

Comment: Just a guess -- you might be running into a limit on what is displayed rather than a limit in how the computations are done. Did you get an error message which reads `ValueError: Exceeds the limit (4300 digits) for integer string conversion; use sys.set_int_max_str_digits() to increase the limit`?

Comment: @JohnColeman I've never seen that message, and I was testing with over 100000 digits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77561307/5987

Comment: @MarkRansom which Python version was that? The 4300 digit limit is in Py >=3.11. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#integer-string-conversion-length-limitation

Comment: @slothrop probably 3.8 or earlier.  It seems that change was backported too: https://discuss.python.org/t/int-str-conversions-broken-in-latest-python-bugfix-releases/18889

Comment: @MarkRansom oh yes you're right, later 3.8.x, 3.9.x, 3.10.x would have it too.

Comment: P.S. the ability to work with huge integers without needing a special library is one of the wonders of Python.  I'm not aware of another language that does that.

Comment: Ok, guys, that basically answers it all. Thanks a lot to each one of you for the valuable insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a strict `int`, Python will correctly add them-

To my knowledge, they're logically unlimited, but practically limited by the operating system, system memory, etc. and how long a user is willing to wait