Multiplication in an arbitrary base in Python
Is there a library or efficient way to perform multiplication in an arbitrary base in Python, without going through the conversion to base 10?
Example of the wanted function f in base 14:
base = 14
a = "b5"
b = "2a"
f(a,b,base) = "22b8"

For convenience, the above values converted in decimal:
int("b5", base) # 159
int("2a", base) # 38 
int("22b8", base) # 6042

This question is limited to integer numbers only.

When you parse a number in some base, you're not converting it to base 10, you're converting it to the internal representation of a number.

The most efficient way to perform this calculation would be to convert to the normal binary representation of integers (in other words, actually perform those int() calls you show), so that you can take advantage of your CPU's multiplication hardware.

@Bill That question requires extra complexity because it has to deal with fractions. If they only need integers, it's much simpler.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-a-string-in-any-base for the inverse of int(str, base)

So what you want is basically def f(a, b, base): return int_to_base(int(a, base) * int(b, base), base) where int_to_base() is one of the functions you can find in that question.

@jasonharper So are you suggesting that the faster way (even for large numbers) is to convert the string with int(string, base), perform the usual multiplication and then convert back, for instance with numpy.base_repr mentioned in the link by @Barmar?

That's almost certainly true. The alternative is writing your own long multiplication function that iterates over the digits. Like how you learned to multiply in grade school.

Python's built-in multiplication is well-optimized C code. I'll bet doing it this way will be 1-2 orders of magnitude faster than a long multiplication function written in python.

Why do you want to avoid doing a conversion in the first place? If it's for efficiency, see what Barmar said. I'm just asking in case there's another reason I haven't thought of. BTW, beware the XY problem.

@Barmar if Python didn't support arbitrary-length integers it could get down to a single CPU instruction.  But even with the overhead of Python integers, I still agree with your assessment of 1-2 orders of magnitude faster than anything you could write yourself.

@wjandrea Yea efficency, I am dealing with repeated operations on very large numbers, so the conversions can become significant (and require sys.set_int_max_str_digits(0) for strings longer than 4300 chars). I was hoping in a faster direct way to multiply them in arbitrary base and after some research I was surprised not to easily find a library to that, hence the question.
