# Permutation algorithm for n characters in x positions

Tags: arrays, algorithm, permutation, heaps-algorithm

e.g. A permutation algorithm for {&, *, %} to be placed in 8 positions:

1. `&&&&&&&&&`
2. `&&&&&&&&*`
3. `&&&&&&&&%`
4. `&&&&&&&*%`
5. `&&&&&&&**`

...

Heap's permutation algorithm I saw on the Internet works just for those who the number of characters are equal to the number of positions, And those who can work with unequal number of characters and number of positions, Only work with integers, Not characters. I also have to say I haven't reached any working algorithm up to now, As I don't know anything about algorithms. I had one try, Which I couldn't name it algorithm after I saw heap's algorithm! In case it helps:

1. Add `&` to the output array.
2. Add `%` to the output array on a new index.
3. Add `*` to the output array on a new index.
4. Do a recursive algorithm for each three.

But I obviously can't handle array indexes.
I have also tried using numbers from 0 to 2 for &, %, *; But I didn't reach a good answer.

Comment: Tip: Use numbers 0, 1 and 2 for representing `&`, `*` and `%`.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen I have tried, Does't work. At least I couldn't find a way to use it.

Comment: 8 positions with 3 possible characters in each position is 3^8 total outputs. So start with a loop that runs 6561 times. The details on where to go from there depend on the programming language that you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard "odometer" method ([IDEOne](https://ideone.com/8fErJh)):

```
static void permute(String str, int len)
{    
  char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

  int[] idx = new int[len];

  char[] perm = new char[len];    
  Arrays.fill(perm, chars[0]);

  while(true)
  {      
    System.out.println(new String(perm));

    int k=idx.length-1;
    for(; k>=0; k--)
    {
      idx[k] += 1;
      if(idx[k] < chars.length) 
      {
        perm[k] = chars[idx[k]];
        break;
      }
      idx[k] = 0;
      perm[k] = chars[idx[k]];
    }
    if(k < 0) break;
  }
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  permute("&*%", 8);
}
```

Output:

```
&&&&&&&&
&&&&&&&*
&&&&&&&%
&&&&&&*&
&&&&&&**
&&&&&&*%
&&&&&&%&
&&&&&&%*
&&&&&&%%
&&&&&*&&
<snip>
%%%%%%**
%%%%%%*%
%%%%%%%&
%%%%%%%*
%%%%%%%%
```

Answer (score 2):

The permutations can be listed out by counting base 3.

- & = 0
- * = 1
- % = 2

## The algorithm (pseudocode)

```
Start i=00000000 and end at 22222222 in base 3:
    str_i = encode i in { &, *, % } character set
    print str_i
    i = i + 1 (in base 3)
```

## Code Example (in Python)

```
def main():
  start = int('00000000', 3)
  end = int('22222222', 3)
  for i in range(start, end + 1):
    # convert binary to base 3
    perm_base3 = str_base(i, 3)
    perm_charset = encode_to_charset(perm_base3)
    print(perm_charset)

# custom character set
# & = 0
# * = 1
# % = 2
def encode_to_charset(str_number_base3):
  ret = []
  for c in str_number_base3:
    if c == '0':
      ret.append('&')
    elif c == '1':
      ret.append('*')
    elif c == '2':
      ret.append('%')
    else:
      pass #TODO handle error here
  return "".join(ret)

#
# Utility functions
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063425/python-elegant-inverse-function-of-intstring-base
#
def digit_to_char(digit):
    if digit < 10: return chr(ord('0') + digit)
    else: return chr(ord('a') + digit - 10)

def str_base(number,base):
    if number < 0:
        return '-' + str_base(-number,base)
    else:
        (d,m) = divmod(number,base)
        if d:
            return str_base(d,base) + digit_to_char(m)
        else:
            return digit_to_char(m)

main()
```

### Live Example (on repl.it)

https://repl.it/@KyleMarshall1/PermutationAlgorithm

Comment: Thank you really for the time you spent for me, But this doesn't work, Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, I just ran it again. Did you try going to the live example on repl.it?

Comment: I ran it again now, OK, I didn't want it to show those with less than 8 positions; But it runs properly.