# Is there any way through which we could define the characters that a hash value is composed of?

Tags: python, hash, cryptography

For example, I want the hash value that I get by using python function blake2b to have only (acdefghjklmnpqrstuvwxyz2345679)

Answer (score 0):

A hash is a bit string. You can *encode* this bit string using a specific set of printable characters if you want. Hexadecimal (using `0123456789abcdef`) is the most common way, but if you want a different set of characters, you can choose those instead.

To encode the hash value in hexadecimal, assuming that you have it as a raw string like the value returned by the `digest` method in the standard `hashlib` module, use `hash.hex()` in Python 3 and `hash.encode('hex')` in Python 2. The `hashlib` module has a method `hexdigest` which returns this encoding directly.

If you want to encode the value using single-case letters and digits without a risk of confusion on `0/O` and `1/I`, there's a standard for that called [Base32](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548.html#section-5). Base32 is available in Python in the [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) module. The standard encoding uses only uppercase, but you can translate to lowercase if you want. Base32 pads with `=`, but you can remove them for storage.

```
import base64, hashlib
hash = hashlib.new('SHA256', b'input').digest()
b32_hash = base64.b32encode(hash).lower().rstrip(b'=')
```

If you really want that specific 30-character set, you can convert the hexadecimal representation to an integer using `int(….hexdigest(), 16)` then [convert that integer to a string using the digits of your choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063425/python-elegant-inverse-function-of-intstring-base).